# Is there a way to make git remember the password for WebDAV remotes?

Tags: git, passwords

I'm working with Git pushing changes to a repository shared over HTTP / WebDAV, and Git prompts for a password for every operation that accesses the HTTP remote. Is there any way to make Git cache the password / have the remote server not prompt me?

The remote webserver should be an Apache and could possibly be reconfigured if necessary.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The way is to use ~/.netrc as outlined in step 3 of [this Git documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt):

> Then, add the following to your $HOME/.netrc (you can do without, but will be
>   asked to input your password a *lot* of times):
>
> ```
> machine <servername>
> login <username>
> password <password>
> ```
>
> ...and set permissions:
>
> ```
> chmod 600 ~/.netrc
> ```

#### UPDATE:

As of git 1.7.9, it seems the way to go would be the native credential helper API. Git comes with a plaintext [credential store](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) or a less convenient but more secure temporary [credential cache](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache). It's also possible to use third-party credential helpers. So far I'm aware of [a helper for the native Windows Credential Store](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/), and [one that integrates with the OS X keychain](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain.c). (The Git build shipped by Homebrew has a binary for it, as might other OS X Git distributions. Github also provides a [standalone binary](http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain).)

Generally, it should be sufficient to set up the a credential helper once:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Or instead of `wincred`, use whichever helper is appropriate for your platform. (If the name of the helper executable is `git-credential-wincred`, the value you set the option to will be `wincred`, etc.)

The credential helpers also support the need to have separate sets of credentials for different repositories on the same host.

Comment: Also, don't include the user name in the URL for git, otherwise git won't consult `~/.netrc`.

Comment: WTF, it implies a single password for all the remote repositories?

Comment: Git doesn't seem to implement any form of authentication internally, instead relying on the transport provider to take care of this. Neither libcurl (used for the HTTP transport), or openssh (used for the "git" transport) are aware of Git repositories, which makes per-repository authentication impossible. (Per-repository _authorization_, however, is possible with gitosis or most of the git hosting services.)

Comment: To answer @OlegMihailik directly: Git uses one login/password pair per remote "machine" when using HTTP, for all repositories on this machine. You could probably circumvent this when using SSH by adding one Host entry per repository into ~/.ssh/config

Comment: I am not sure what the servername in ~/.netrc is. But anyway "github.com" is working for github.com repository.

Comment: @JoonhoPark the whole `~/.netrc` thing is (thankfully) hopelessly obsolete now, every OS gives you solid integration with native credential management out of the box these days.

Answer (score 37):

Run this command inside your repo:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Then push to the server once:

```
git push
```

The credentials you use to push to the server will get saved in `~/.git-credentials`.

Instructions taken from this guide [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store).

Comment: the best and simplest way

Comment: Agree with nebulabox and sidhi... I don't know why this has so few votes

Comment: didn't work for me. The same problem it asks again.

Comment: @SananAli OMA! first person with the same name as mine, also same problem :(

Answer (score 17):

Why can't you just use password in remote url?

```
$ git config remote.origin.url = http://username:password@origin_link.com/repository.git
```

Comment: This seems like a good option if you need to have a different username/password for two repositories on the same host. (A disadvantage is that at least I am more likely to make sure that `~/.netrc` isn't world-readable than doing so for every `.git/config`)