# Syncing with github

Tags: github

This is for the nth time that I'm trying to connect to my github account and its becoming increasingly frustrating at my failure to do this.

I followed this tutorial step by step [Github setup on windows](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) but I failed at step 5, i.e. Test everything out.

```
ssh git@github.com
```

gives me this

```
ssh: github.com: no address associated with name
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the default git installation which comes with railsinstaller on Windows XP (behind a proxy)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to at least set an `HTTP_PROXY` variable environment.

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

Or, for bash session:

```
 export http_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
 export https_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

Make sure `%HOME%` (or $HOME) is set to a directory where you did store your `.ssh` config

Then, for git commands:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo \\bin\\curl-ca-bundle.crt
git config --global http.proxy http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
git config --global user.name <short_username>
git config --global user.email <email>
git config --global github.user <github_username>
git config --global github.token <github_token>
```

Note: for bash session:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

To avoid GitHub asking for your password, create a `_netrc` file in your `HOME` (or a `.netrc` for bash session)

```
machine github.com
login <login_github>
password <password_github>
```

---

Update 2012

Note that [since git1.7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938677/6309) (2012), you can use a [credential caching mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2240590/6309) in order to avoid having to store in plain text your login/password (in a `%HOME%/_netrc` file).

Comment: If your having an error about \\bin \\ curl-ca-bundle.crt, you can use: git config --global http.sslverify "false"

Comment: @GonzaloJarjury That would not be a practice I would recommend. Always try to verify your certificates. Try first, even on Windows with recent version of Git: `git config --system http.sslcainfo /ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Is ```<login_internet>``` the WiFi name?

Comment: @McFloofenbork 8 years later, I believe the "login_internet" represents your login account you would use to authenticate to the proxy.

Comment: what are the <login_internet> and <login_password>?

Comment: @Sara Same: an enterprise proxy needs the credentials of your current Windows or Mac session: your login and password for your current OS session.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't have a proxy enabled and the problem persists, I found the solution! It's a problem with Yosemite. Apple replaced the mDNSResponder by the discoveryd. It's a service and you can unload and load it back:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

This post explains every detail:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

in edge cases it might not be the proxy that is causing the issues more like the DNS settings.

Test if DNS resolve works or not

```
nslookup archive.ubuntu.com
```

If correctly setup, you will see IP address, if broken you will see error message.

How to check DNS config (Ubuntu)
`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. T># [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

You can use these two Google DNS Servers for testing.

Try nslookup command again. If it works now, It´s been an DNS issue all along.

Test github connection

1. SSH

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Output if successfull will look something like this

```
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Hi <YourUsername>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

2. HTTPS
   Try simply do clone e.g.
   `git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife`

If issues are fixed, it will prompt for username and password.

Comment: thanks! I've got suddenly "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...': Could not resolve host: github.com" by given "git pull". Updating /etc/resolv.conf like here helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, are you also behind a firewall? Please try to run `ssh -v git@github.com` to see what's going on behind the scenes. For my setup, my `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
Host github.com
ProxyCommand /c/windows/connect.exe -H name_of_proxy:8080 %h %p
User git
Port 443
Hostname ssh.github.com
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The ProxyCommand is described [here](http://bent.latency.net/bent/git/goto-san-connect-1.85/src/connect.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a firewall. However, the proxy i'm using is a script and not a static address. How can I take that into account in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might not have configured your SSH config properly. The reason github.com is unresolvable is because you are probably pointed to a DNS server that doesn't resolve queries outside your domain.

I wrote a whole blog post about this so take a look here:
http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html

Hope this helps.