# git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command

Tags: git, msysgit, git-bash, git-config

I followed [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) to the letter, including the part about password caching. It seems like the instructions are wrong, because every time I `git push origin master` I get this error:

```
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'get --help'.
```

... at which point I am forced to enter my username and password. After doing so, I am presented with the same error message again, followed by the output from `git push`.

Here is the contents of my .gitconfig file:

```
[user]
    name = myusername
    email = myusername@myemaildomain.com
[credential]
    helper = cache
```

To be clear, after I installed Git and ran Git Bash, here is exactly what I typed:

```
git config --global user.name "myusername"
git config --global user.email "myusername@myemaildomain.com"
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Please help. This is so frustrating!

Comment: To remove the message, "git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command.", run "git config --global --unset credential.helper", then you can follow the instructions below.

Comment: @Wally +1 Thanks, your command worked for me only after removing `--global`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Comment: you can alternatively remove the message by modifying .git/config file manually (i.e remove the lines below [credential])

Comment: FWIW for those reading the various Windows suggestions below, `git config credential.helper cache` _did_ work for  me with Cygwin git version 2.13.2.

Comment: Accepted and popular answers below are now out of date, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105688/3066295

Comment: For those still getting this message after running a git fetch or pull cmd, check the config files manually: `git config --global -e` and `git config --local -e`
In trying to reset my credentials in Windows, I accidently added a line to the local file causing the error. To remove the credentials I followed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git which worked.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

From [a blog I found](http://blog.sdbarker.com/2012/07/09/git-credential-caching-on-windows/):

> This [git-credential-cache] doesn’t work for Windows systems as git-credential-cache communicates through a Unix socket.

**Git for Windows**

Since msysgit has been superseded by Git for Windows, using [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) is now the easiest option. Some versions of the Git for Windows installer (e.g. 2.7.4) have a checkbox during the install to enable the Git Credential Manager. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of Git For Windows 2.7.4 install wizard]

**Still using msysgit? For msysgit versions 1.8.1 and above**

The `wincred` helper was added in msysgit 1.8.1. Use it as follows:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

**For msysgit versions older than 1.8.1**

First, download [git-credential-winstore](https://github.com/anurse/git-credential-winstore/downloads) and install it in your git bin directory.

Next, make sure that the directory containing `git.cmd` is in your Path environment variable. The default directory for this is *C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd* on a 64-bit system or *C:\Program Files\Git\cmd* on a 32-bit system. An easy way to test this is to launch a command prompt and type `git`. If you don't get a list of git commands, then it's not set up correctly.

Finally, launch a command prompt and type:

```
git config --global credential.helper winstore
```

Or you can edit your `.gitconfig` file manually:

```
[credential]
    helper = winstore
```

Once you've done this, you can manage your git credentials through Windows Credential Manager which you can pull up via the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/ contains FAQ. It helped me to install winstore successfully. Binary crashes unless you run it from git-bash.

Comment: FYI I had to install with explicit admin rights.  Without it, I was getting error "git: 'credential-winstore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'".  My .gitconfig now looks a bit different also, with the [credential line] having "helper = !'C:\\Users\\Malachi\\AppData\\Roaming\\GitCredStore\\git-credential-winstore.exe''

Comment: mine throws an unhandled exception and dies -- System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Comment: I had to follow the step on this link to completely get it working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107833/git-credential-winstore-prompt-does-not-work-with-self-hosted-repositories

Comment: Is there a reason as to why they would use Unix sockets in a multi-platform application? And if so, why does git-credential-winstore does not ship with the Windows version of Git by default?

Comment: The git-credential-winstore tool is not working for me. It used to, but suddenly I'm getting prompted all over the place. I've checked .git-config and the Windows Credential Manager and everything is there that should be. It's simply not working and I really don't have any idea why. :(

Comment: This has been essentially superseded by the wincred manager included with msysgit.

Comment: If you are using **git** through **cygwin**, you can place *git-credential-winstore* in the same directory as your *git* executable (probably `/bin`).

Comment: How do I update these settings if I've already installed without selecting the right option? Do I have to reinstall at that point?

Comment: @ButtleButkus In that case I believe you'll just execute `git config --global credential.helper wincred` at the command line. (This depends on which version of git you have installed of course.)

Comment: @NateCook I decided to update to latest version for windows, apparently 2.8.2. Mine was 2.7-ish from last October. So I chose the correct settings this time but I'm getting this error when running `git fetch`: "git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."

Comment: @ButtleButkus Do you by chance have multiple versions of git installed? (Maybe check the path with `where git` at the command line.) Also check the answers to this related question to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060572/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command-remove-setting

Comment: Last method is really useful for git installations in MSys2, which works better for me because it has a different home location. (We have network home drives at work. (Yuck!))

Answer (score 89):

Looks like `git` now comes with `wincred` out-of-the-box on Windows (msysgit):

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

**Reference**:
https://github.com/msysgit/git/commit/e2770979fec968a25ac21e34f9082bc17a71a780

Comment: Note that this is not as secure as the in-memory cache. also the 'wincred' option is outdated.

Comment: This was answered 7 years ago. Not sure what the current state of msysgit is

Answer (score 38):

1. Run `git config --global credential.helper wincred`
2. Go to: `CONTROL PANEL\CREDENTIAL MANAGER\WINDOWS CREDENTIAL\GENERIC CREDENTIAL`
3. Click in add a credential in `Internet or network address:`  add
   `git:https://`{username}`.github.com`
   `User:` {name}
   `Password:` {Password}

Comment: Credential Manager is in User Accounts and Family Safety in Windows 7

Comment: THANK YOU! It took me an hour to find out how to fix my Windows Credential Manager after changing my domain password. Holy moly, what a maze.

Comment: `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}` from the console will start the Credential Manager as well.

Comment: Thanks, my issue is fixed :)

Comment: What about `Azure git repo`? I only have the clone URL as `https://<user>@dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<azure-project>/_git/<repo-name>`. When I enter this as Internet or web address, it is invalid.

Comment: I figured it out^^. In case of Azure repos, we can use either HTTPS or SSH connection. I had to configure `git://<org-name>@dev.azure.com/<org-name>` as Internet address, `org-name` as username and `PAT token` as password. Then, I had to execute `$ git config --global credential.helper wincred` to set proper credential helper.

Answer (score 29):

I faced this problem while using AptanaStudio3 on windows7. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/1344509#remove-credentials-from-git) helped me:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Answer (score 26):

For git version >=1.7.10 (check with `git --version`), use this method (from [reference](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)):

Windows:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Mac:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Comment: On Mac. Do `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`

Answer (score 18):

A similar error is `'credential-wincred' is not a git command`

### The accepted and popular answers are now out of date...

> `wincred` is for the project git-credential-winstore which is [no longer maintained](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gitcredentialstore).
>
> It was replaced by **[Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)** maintained by [Microsoft open source](https://opensource.microsoft.com/).

Download the release as zip file from link above and extract contents to

```
\cygwin\usr\libexec\git-core
```

(or `\cygwin64\usr\libexec\git-core` as it may be)

Then enable it, (by setting the global `.gitconfig`) - execute:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

**How to use**

> No further config is needed.
>
> It works [automatically] when credentials are needed.
>
> For example, when pushing to Azure DevOps, it opens a window and initializes an oauth2 flow to get your token.

ref:

- https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/318
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows#installation-in-an-msys2-environment

Comment: This worked for me except I had to add --replace-all as well as I had multiple credential.helper entries in my config.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this issue by removing the `credential` section from the config of specific project:

- Just typed: `git config -e`
- Inside the editor I removed the whole section **`[credential] helper = cache`**.

This removed the annoying message :

`git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: I tried many solutions from above and this is the only one that worked. I just went to my .git folder, opened the config file and deleted
[credential]  helper = global (I set it to "global" accidentally).
Thanks a lot Pini Cheyni.

Comment: This is, indeed, the easier way to do. BTW, you can add `--global` if you cannot find the `helper`. You can also change `cache` to `manager` which is the default value for `helper`

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
git credential-manager-core configure
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

There is now a much easier way to setup Git password caching by double clicking a small *exe* on Windows. The program is still based on `git-credential-winstore` mentioned by the top voted answer, although the project has been moved from GitHub to http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/

You can download the exe (and a binary for Mac) from this blog post: https://github.com/blog/1104-credential-caching-for-wrist-friendly-git-usage

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Microsoft has started maintaining this project. It stores the passwords in the windows credential store.

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting similar error when I tried to use command "git pull" from master branch.

```
Error: "git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."
```

I executed below two commands and issue got resolved.

```
$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
$ git config credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of others who come on this issue, I had this same problem in Ubuntu (namely that my passwords weren't caching, despite having set the option correctly, and getting the error `git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command.`), until I found out that **this feature is only available in Git 1.7.9 and above**.

Being on an older distribution of Ubuntu (Natty; I'm a stubborn Gnome 2 user) the version in the repo was git version 1.7.4.1.  I used the following PPA to upgrade:
https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa

Comment: I am still getting `git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command.` even after upgrading to version 2.8.2 on Windows, even though the credential cache is working! I probably created this problem by using some `git config` command before.

Comment: @ButtleButkus git config alters either `~/.gitconfig` or the repo-local `.git/config`, depending on whether the `--global` flag was used. Look at those two files for anything related to credentials.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of others having this issue - I landed here because I tried to get cute with how I set up a new github repository, but per the [setup page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) credential helper doesn't work unless you clone a repository.

"Tip: The credential helper only works when you clone an HTTPS repository URL. If you use the SSH repository URL instead, SSH keys are used for authentication. This guide offers help generating and using an SSH key pair."

Answer (score 4):

I realize I'm a little late to the conversation, but I encountered the exact same issue
In my git config I had two entries credentials…

**In my .gitconfig file**

```
[credential]
helper = cached
[credentials]
helper = wincred
```

**The Fix: Changed my .gitconfig file to the settings below**

```
[credential]
helper = wincred
[credentials]
helper = wincred
```

Comment: I think the `[credentials]` key can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 4):

On an older Ubuntu Linux system:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 2):

Dev. 2022 for [Git 2.39.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/v2.39.0.windows.1)+ and [GCM v2.0.877](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.877) (Nov. 2022), [PR 551](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/551):
[image: GCM no core]

> `warning`: `git-credential-manager-core` was renamed to `git-credential-manager`
> `warning`: see https://aka.ms/gcm/rename for more information

The current packaged credential helper with Git for Windows (2.38.1.windows.1, Oct. 2022), is

```
 git config credential.helper
 manager

 where git-credential-manager-core
 c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git-credential-manager.exe
```

Up to Oct. 2022, it was `manager-core`.

This is after GCM (Git Credential Manager): [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager/`](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager)

> Git Credential Manager (GCM) is a secure [Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) built on [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) that runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux. It aims to provide a consistent and secure authentication experience, including multi-factor auth, to every major source control hosting service and platform.

GCM supports (in alphabetical order) [Azure DevOps](https://dev.azure.com/), Azure DevOps Server (formerly Team Foundation Server), Bitbucket, GitHub, and GitLab.
Compare to Git's [built-in credential helpers](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) (Windows: `wincred`, macOS: `osxkeychain`, Linux: `gnome-keyring/libsecret`), which provide single-factor authentication support for username/password only.

GCM replaces both the .NET Framework-based [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) and the Java-based [Git Credential Manager for Mac and Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux).

Note that the [latest release v2.0.866](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.866) (Nov. 2022) drops `-core` suffix from entry executable ([PR 551](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/551))

> Rename the main entry executable from `git-credential-manager-core(.exe)` to simply `git-credential-manager(.exe)`, now that the older GCM4W has been removed from the Git for Windows project as an option (and the GCMC project has been renamed).
>
> To help with migration somewhat, create symlinks and shim/copy-executables for the original executable name "`git-credential-manager-core(.exe)`" for consumers who have not updated to the new version.

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), unix socket start  to be considered for Git for Windows:

See [commit bb390b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb390b1f49406d967e8bf3401337cf1d9535f820), [commit 245670c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/245670cd46c4713818b5fbca2c084ce2e19f4ed8), [commit 0fdcfa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fdcfa2f9f59a8bf4202ac3933991f42a4ac1393) (14 Sep 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2e7990](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2e799012b3657f4f91560d299b5606c297e7cf7), 23 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-compat-util`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb390b1f49406d967e8bf3401337cf1d9535f820): include declaration for unix sockets in windows
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> Available since Windows 10 release 1803 and Windows Server 2019.
>
> `NO_UNIX_SOCKETS` is still the default for Windows builds, as they need to keep backward compatibility with releases up to Windows 7, but allow including the header otherwise.

Comment: So it sounds like the Git update I do tomorrow (Nov 2022) might break my current install?  Just like the update I did yesterday (Oct 2022) broke an install that was working fine for *YEARS*?   Sigh... If the install is going to use a new name ... why doesn't it update `~/.gitconfig` automatically?  Or at least tell the user to update ~/.gitconfig manually?

Comment: @paulsm4 I agree, this is unfortunate. And can be reported in [Git For Windows issues](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) once this is released.

Comment: Anyway - thank you for the comprehensive, up-to-date info on this thread.  +1: much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I literally just went through this!

1. Download Git Credential Manager Core and Install it: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#download-and-install
2. Go to the `Account Settings > Emails` on GitHub. Your should see something like this:
   [image]
3. The highlighted email is system generated to keep your private email private. Now copy that and use it in the next step
4. Configure git:

```
 git config --global user.name "yourusername"
 git config --global user.email "1234567+yourgithubusername@users.noreply.github.com"
 git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Now, your git commands should work again.

Minor note: I'm using Linux Mint. YMMV

Additional note: There is a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/528) in Git Credential Manager Core v 2.0.567 in their Debian backage. Please install [v2.0.474](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/tag/v2.0.474) before the new version is out.

Comment: Simply installing the latest version of Git (for me it was at https://gitforwindows.org), fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

Another efficient workaround is:

1- Go to control panel and add your credentials for github.com like this:

[image: Windows Credentials for GitHub]

2- go to CMD and enter these commands:

- a- cd %localappdata%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\mingw32\bin\
- b-   git.exe config --edit --system
- c- correct last line with:
  helper = manager
- d- Save the new config file by clicking on CTRL+C then typing :wq then hit Enter

[image: update configuration: helper = manager]

This works perfectly for me!

Comment: What is CMD and where is it?

Answer (score 2):

In my case this command solved the issue:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core --replace-all
```

for using the new net-core credential manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had three different `helper=` entries in my .gitconfig's [credential] section, one of them empty. Deleting the other two and keeping `helper=wincred` solved the problem for me.

BTW: I don't know why, but I didn't find my .gitconfig right away. I found it then in C:\Users\username.

Comment: SUGGESTION: If you use Git bash (or happen to be in a MacOS or Linux terminal prompt), your .gitconfig should be here: `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with our Azure DevOps repositories after our domain changed, i.e. from @xy.com to @xyz.com. To fix this issue, we generated a fresh personal access token with the following permissions:

Code: read & write
Packaging: read

Then we opened the Windows Credential Manager, added a new generic windows credential with the following details:

**Internet or network address:** "git:{*projectname*}@dev.azure.com/{*projectname*}" - alternatively you should use your git repository name here.
**User name:** "Personal Access Token"
**Password:** {*The generated Personal Access Token*}

Afterwards all our git operations were working again. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

On mac run following command:

`git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`

Answer (score -1):

My original answer turned out to not be very useful even for myself, so I looked a bit more into it, and I found a hack (albeit somewhat complicated).

So, I use `git` under MSYS2, and I would like to use `credential-cache`, to just remember my password temporarily (and I haven't seen such a use case with `wincred` or other Windows-applicable approaches).

Basically, this requires a hack in https://github.com/git/git/blob/55144cc/builtin/credential-cache--daemon.c#L239 - instead of `die`-ing in that line, we'd like to proceed.

So, first of all, we want to build `git` under MSYS2.

- Problem 1: You cannot just build the proper https://github.com/git/git under MSYS2, linking stage will fail with "*src/git/cache.h:1262: undefined reference to `win32_has_dos_drive_prefix'*" and similar messages

So, we need to build the actual `git` as used in MSYS2. First, check versions:

```sh
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0
$ pacman -Ss git | grep installed # msys/git 2.33.0-1 (VCS) [installed]
```

Then, as per https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Creating-Packages/, we can do this:

```sh
$ git clone "https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages"
$ cd MSYS2-packages/
$ cd git
$ makepkg -sCLf
==> Making package: git 2.33.0-1 (Thu, Sep 23, 2021 12:47:33 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
...
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/src/MSYS2-packages/git/src/git-2.33.0'
make[1]: 'GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/src/MSYS2-packages/git/src/git-2.33.0'
sed -e '1s|#!.*/sh|#!/bin/sh|' git-subtree.sh >git-subtree
chmod +x git-subtree
make: Leaving directory '/c/src/MSYS2-packages/git/src/git-2.33.0/contrib/subtree'
==> Starting check()...
```

Note here:

- This build process first ends up in a ASCIIDOC/XMLTO part, which like takes half an hour on my machine
- Then it ends up in a `*** prove ***` part which takes even longer, but can be interrupted with Ctrl-C, and the built executables will not be erased.

So, now we want to do a hack in the source; note:

- If we do a hack in the source, we do **NOT** want to use `makepkg -sCLf`, because that will erase the source directory (along with all the built .exe artefacts), and then reconstruct it before build

So, we make our hack with `sed`, and then build:

```sh
$ sed -i 's/die(_(permissions_advice), dir);/fprintf(stderr, "Permissions on cached credentials socket directory %s are too loose, but HACK: going on\\n", dir);/' ./src/git-2.33.0/builtin/credential-cache--daemon.c
$ (cd src/git-2.33.0/; make)
    CC builtin/credential-cache--daemon.o
    LINK git.exe
...
    SUBDIR templates
```

At this point, note that the hack ends up in at least three executables, which can be confirmed with:

```sh
$ grep -ao ....HACK........ ./src/git-2.33.0/git-credential-cache--daemon.exe
$ grep -ao ....HACK........ ./src/git-2.33.0/git-credential-cache.exe
$ grep -ao ....HACK........ ./src/git-2.33.0/git.exe
```

... and I could only get this to work, after replacing all three:

```sh
# backup the original files:

$ mv /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-cache--daemon.exe /usr/lib/git-core/__git-credential-cache--daemon_orig.exe
$ mv -v /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-cache.exe /usr/lib/git-core/__git-credential-cache__orig.exe
$ mv -v /usr/bin/git.exe /usr/bin/__git_orig.exe
$ mv -v /usr/lib/git-core/git.exe /usr/lib/git-core/__git_orig.exe

# copy over the hacked files:

cp -v ./src/git-2.33.0/git-credential-cache--daemon.exe /usr/lib/git-core/
cp -v ./src/git-2.33.0/git-credential-cache.exe /usr/lib/git-core/
cp -v ./src/git-2.33.0/git.exe /usr/bin/
cp -v ./src/git-2.33.0/git.exe /usr/lib/git-core/
```

And at this point, `credential-cache` started working also for me on MSYS2 (caching passwords for a limited amount of time); it's just that it dumps the hacked line when starting up:

```sh
$ git pull
Password for 'https://user@git.mysite.com':
Permissions on cached credentials socket directory /home/user/.cache/git/credential are too loose, but HACK: going on
Already up to date.

# second pull, password is cached
$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

A bit tricky, but seems to work.

PS: A tricky thing was, that I originally replaced `die` with just a `printf` to `stdout`, but that kept on failing; it turns out, `stdout` is used for interprocess communication, and for this to succeed, something apparently answers `ok\0` on `stdout` which is three bytes; so the solution was to print the notice to `stderr` instead.

---

(original answer):

While not responsive to the question exactly as asked, this was the most appropriate question I could find, to document this as an answer:

I use `git` under MSYS2 in Windows 10, which currently has the version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.32.0
```

I typically just want git to cache my password for a limited time (maybe 10 minutes or so) and then forget about it; and I haven't yet seen uses of `wincred` or other Windows-specific credential manager with that use case.

That being said, turns out for me there is an "easy fix" - basically, the first time credential manager runs, it is fine; it is only upon subsequent uses that I get:

```
$ git push
Password for 'http://user@githost.example.com':
fatal: The permissions on your socket directory are too loose; other
users may be able to read your cached credentials. Consider running:

        chmod 0700 /home/user/.cache/git/credential
fatal: cache daemon did not start:
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
...
```

So, basically, the fix is to delete the `credential` directory - thereafter, the credential cache manager runs as if for the first time, and caches the passwords for a limited time - just as I want it:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/git/credential


# note below, the very first pull still asks for a password:

$ git pull
Password for 'http://user@githost.example.com':
Already up to date.

# ... but the second pull does not, it uses credentials cache

$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

Good enough for me, I guess `:)`

EDIT: not really, I've experienced that immediately after this, if you try a pull in another tab, the error returns.