# Can't login to Bitbucket on 'Github for Windows'

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, github-for-windows

I've followed the tutorials on how to make Github for Windows work with Bitbucket,

And in some point where you try to login I get this strange bug or anything.

Here's the image:

[image: Ok not possible]

The problem is I can't click the login button and I have no idea why.
I'm stuck and can't proceed on the tutorial.

Comment: Tried to reinstall Github for Windows. Still can't click the button. :(

Comment: Did you have a chance to try this on the latest github for windows client released a few days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That login is for using bitbucket with https url (and [I did manage to get it working at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665100/6309)).

If the https address doesn't work, [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) can offer an alternative GUI.

---

But as shown in [this tutorial](http://blog.stevebumbaugh.com/post/24107268483/github-for-windows-client-for-bitbucket) (or even [this one](http://faisonz.com/github-for-windows-and-bitbucket/)), you could also use GitHub for Windows with **ssh addresses**.

> Make a backup of the ‘`github_rsa.pub`’ SSH public key file.
>   Copy the contents of `C:\Users\{user}\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to this file and save it.
>
> - Visit the GitHub site and create an account if you don’t already have one: https://github.com/settings/ssh
> - `Account > Edit your profile > SSH keys`
> - Add a new key with the label: “`Default Public Key (nopass)`”
> - Copy the public key (`C:\Users\{user}.ssh\id_rsa.pub`) to GitHub

---

The one tutorial I have found for using BitBucket repos with https url is [this one](https://coderwall.com/p/x6xhta) ([from Jeremy](https://coderwall.com/zaus)):

> - Install GitHub for Windows (GH4W), open program
> - Set your username/email globally to get the right avatar in non-github projects

```
git config —global user.name “FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME”
git config —global user.email “MY_NAME@example.com”
```

> - Add new repository (either preexisting or blank directory)
> - In the repository, click the "tools" > "settings" link at the top
> - Go to BitBucket, find your clone link -- choose "HTTPS" option
> - Back in GH4W, in the "primary remote (origin)" box enter the link you got in step #4
> - Update the settings
> - Back in the repo view of GH4W, click the "publish" link at the top
> - Wait while it spins, then confirm it's there in the remote.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I've followed your tutorial and also step 4 which is important. I've added my publc SSH key on my github account. And when I click on publish it gives me an error of 'failed to publish this branch: please make sure the repository exist and that you have permissions to write to it'

Comment: @DavidMandeeli by my tutorial, you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664949/use-github-for-windows-for-both-bitbucket-and-github/13665100#13665100?

Comment: Yea, sorry I can actually work on the Git bash + Bitbucket. But I really like the features of GH4W. I'm still trying to figure it out how to make it work. Yes that's the tutorial I followed. I was stuck at the Login part because I can't click login.

Comment: I got the https code and inserted it on the 'primary remote' option in GH4W, then I tried to click 'publish' and gave me this error. 'failed to publish this branch: please make sure the repository exist and that you have permissions to write to it'

Comment: @DavidMandeeli in that repo (you are trying to publish), did you set the right `user.name` and `user.email`?

Comment: in --global configs?. Yes I did set it. Entered my user.name = bitbucket acc & user.email = email i used in bitbucket

Comment: @DavidMandeeli yes, global or local. Did you use the same url as I did: `https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo` (with the user login included in the url)?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the git bash. Cause I'm working on a team project right now i'm still new to this and we want the project to be private so we used bitbucket instead. 

My other mate created the project > i cloned it (successful on git bash). Tried to commmit changes and once I 'git push origin master'

It returned a Permission denied (public key) could not read from remote repos

Comment: @DavidMandeeli Did you use the same url as I did: `https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo` (with the user login included in the url)?

Comment: @DavidMandeeli what is exactly the url you are using for your remote `origin`?

Comment: Hi yes I did put that one and when I update, it asks for a login. And that I can;t click the login button that's why I can;t proceed with the tutorial you made.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29165/discussion-between-david-mandeeli-and-vonc)

Comment: @DavidMandeeli (chat is blocked at work) First, what `git remote -v` returns when executed within your local clone. Second, did your colleague declare your account in a team (http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/05/30/bitbucket-teams/) or added you (your account or your public ssh key) as a collaborator for the private repo he created?

Comment: yes we have, and the project is a repository in the Team account.

This is the result of the git remote -v

`origin git clone git@bitbucket.org:davidcs/test.git (fetch)`
`origin git clone git@bitbucket.org:davidcs/test.git (push)`

Comment: Ok now I can psuh changes using my account to the team repository. I think I was just in the wrong directory. But will try it on GH4W now.

Comment: @DavidMandeeli so you are using an ssh address! But my tutorial was for an https address.

Comment: If i used "https://davidcs@bitbucket.org/myteam/myproject.git" it asks me for a login. That's why I can't commit and publish changes using GH4W. But I can on git bash. : /

Comment: Try using `https://davidcs@bitbucket.org/myteam/myproject` as a remote url (no `.git` at the end) in GH4W.

Comment: it's still asking me for a login though :(

Comment: @DavidMandeeli it will always ask you for a login, with https address. But can you click on 'Ok'?

Comment: No, it's really weird cause I can;t click it.

Comment: I can login on git bash without any problems, I've reinstalled my GH4W too.

Comment: @DavidMandeeli just to be sure, could you launch your GH4W with elevated privileges ("As Administrator"), in case this is a weird right issue?

Comment: I'm using windows 8, and tried running it as an Admin on the "windows 8 metro view" but nothing shows up. I think because this is not a .exe application. It's .appref-ms as shown in the file. Hmm if I right click it no "run as" option shows.

Comment: Hi my sourcetree problem awhile ago was fixed during this process. I'll proceed on using SourceTree. I'll pass on GH4W. Thanks @VonC. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DavidMandeeli You are welcome. I have added a reference to SourceTree in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue previously however newer versions appear to have fixed this. If you have further issues just pull the repo down using Git Shell initially and your issues should be fixed.

1. Open Git Shell (from start menu)
2. `cd ~/Documents/GitHub` to get into your home directory
3. `git clone http://therepo.com/the/repo.git`
4. Open GitHub for Windows, click the Local Repositories section
5. Open the GitHub folder in your documents folder
6. Drag the repo folder into GitHub for Windows
7. All should work fine now

Comment: Interesting to know, simpler than my ssh approach described in my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

i recently had the same issue with GH4W. It turned out that i was logged in to GitHub while i tried to connect to a Beanstalk repository. When i logged out at GitHub the Ok button became clickable and i could successfully connect to Beanstalk.

Comment: Good to know, and complement my own answer. +1