# Cannot push to github with Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, github

In Powershell Console, when typing

```
git remote add github https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
git push -u github master
```

Powershell prompt

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

But I cannot enter any answer as any keypress doesn't seem to respond, is it normal ?

Note 1: I use github as name for remote because I already used origin for pushing also to bitbucket

Note 2: I am on Windows 10 and have installed Posh-Git

Comment: Are you using the ISE?  If so, that doesn't offer programs the ability to read console input... I've solved this before by running Start-Process which will launch it in a new window.  Or just using the console instead of ISE.

Comment: @ChrisN no I'm using non ISE console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the process non-interactive with:

- using your username in the url:

  ```
  git remote add github https://myusername@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
  ```
- [using a git credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) that will [store your password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310274/6309) for you

  ```
  git config --global credential.helper wincred
  ```

Comment: thanks that's usefull answer I will mark it as good answer if nobody can fully answer as my question also pertains to Powershell not just git.