# git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command - Remove setting

Tags: git, caching, config

After *attempting* to setup git credential cache on Windows 7 I would now like to scrap the idea and remove this error message and setting from git.

`git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command.`

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693074/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command) shows how to fix this error by installing additional software to make the credential caching work -- I however wish to remove this setting all together.

How do I do this?

I have tried:
`git config --global --remove-section credential-cache` and variations thereof.
Also it does not exist in my .git/config file either.

Comment: What are you doing to *cause* that error message?

Comment: @greg-hewgill git pull or push

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Running `git config --global -e` allowed me to remove the offending config setting from the global git config.

```
[credential]
helper = winstore
```

Comment: Make sure to check your local (and possibly system) configs as well - git config -e loads up the config for the current repository.  You can have credential helpers defined in multiple places, this helped me ferret out a second helper I had defined in a specific repository.

Comment: With older versions winstore or cache might not work. I used  `[credential] helper = wincred` based on [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11889392/922741] and happy days

Comment: @claudekennilol Presumably they removed those lines (in VIM you can press 'dd' on a line to delete it) and saved the file by typing :wq!

Comment: thanks! this works well. I did go with wincred vs winstore

Answer (score 15):

I ran `git config --global -e` but it did not contain any sections related to credentials.

However, when I ran `git config -e` I did find there was a `[credential]` section.

The following command resolved the issue for me.

`git config --remove-section credential`

Comment: How can I reward you with some reputation? This solved a freaking problem!

Answer (score 14):

I had same problem with error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

So I decided to get rid of credential caching altogether, and I did it with in Git bash:

```
git config --global -e
```

then I found

```
[credential]
    helper = cache
```

and deleted it, saved file and after I tried again result was:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

So error gone away.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why the error occurred ?

Answer (score 7):

Just reaffirming what Bradley Flood correctly said, running `git config --global -e` worked for me too and to extend on this the config setting I deleted was:

```
    [credential]
    helper = winstore
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue in ubuntu ,just type below command in terminal.

```
sudo git config --system --unset credential.helper manager
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
git config --system -e
```

press 'I' for edit;

remove code

```
[credential]
helper=xxxxxx
```

press 'Esc' for close editor and write ':wq' to exit from editor;

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem -

```
$ git push
git: 'credential-user.name' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
git: 'credential-user.email' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
git: 'credential---replace-all' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

So I decided to get rid of all credential caching:

```
git config --global -e
```

Here you can remove all the *helper* lines -

```
[credential]
        helper = xxxx
```

Save it and try again:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

If you want to store your git password in your local PC so that you don't need to enter it everytime then try:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

This will add:

```
[credential]
        helper = store
```

And then retry `git push` and give username and password once. After this, you won't have to give username and password anymore for your `git pull` or `git push` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, the reason was instead for pulling the branch from remote 'feat_x', I created the branch 'feat_x' in my local repo.  Here fix was to delete the branch from local repo and pull it again from the remote.