# 'Not a git command' when trying to push

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm brand new to Git and am having some issues when trying to push. Note that I have been successfully pushing all day. I was trying to store credentials and when trying to undo some work I think I made a typo and now when I try to push to my repo I get the following:

```
$ git push
git: 'credential---unset-all' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I was trying to clear saved credentials and was guessing at commands. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Please note that performing the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693074/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command) do not solve my problem.

Thanks!

**Another note:** notice how there is '---' (i.e. three dashes instead of a space and two dashes); I think that is part of this issue. It's like I modified the `push` command but I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Use "git remote" to list your remotes.  It looks like things that look like command line flags have gotten into your remote names.

Comment: @antlersoft `git remote` just returns `origin`

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693074/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command

Comment: @sauumum Sorry, no luck with that solution. I had already tried it before posting my own question :(

Comment: @tmwoods -- Sorry, I meant 'git remote --verbose'; any surprises there?

Comment: @antlersoft No, looks legit. Same url for `origin`, one has (fetch) and the other has (push) at the end

Comment: Do you have any git aliases or pre-push hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had somehow updated the global config file. I had added 'credential.helper' there, so I just had to remove it.

Typing `git config -l` showed the problem, then typing `git config --unset credential.helper` removed it from that list.