# I keep getting this warning when push to git repo

Tags: git, window

```
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no Unix socket support
git credential-'cache store: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
git credential-'cache store: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no Unix socket support
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this warning on every push to my public repo.

I uninstalled git from my pc and project. Re-Initialized it but, the warning still persists.

Also, I remember entering some configuration in credential store to stop git from repeatedly asking password. However, I don't remember which file it was or how to access it.

Is this error coming from the **credentials cache store file**? If yes how to **reset or delete** it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check to see what's in your `~/.gitconfig` file if anything looks out of place. Maybe even delete/rename it to see if that changes things. Maybe change your credential helper to `manager` or `manager-core`. What do you see when you run the command `git config credential.helper`?

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11889392/13847690)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, from docs of GitHub:

> You can also install a native Git shell, such as Git for Windows. With
> Git for Windows, running the following in the command line will store
> your credentials:
>
> $ git config --global credential.helper wincred