# Azure DevOps Server Build Agent on Windows XP

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to install Agent on windows XP?

I know it is possible to install on Linux - could not find a way to install on Windows XP

I only need to run the build on the XP machine

Using Azure DevOps Server 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Using Jenkins which can install agent on windows XP.

Set Web-hooks to connect to Jenkins server

Problems

Very Slow GIT pull/clone/push on Windows XP

PowerShell Scripts are limited to Windows XP PowerShell version

Git Version Limited to Git-2.10.0-32-bit

LFS version Limited to git-lfs-windows-v2.8.0 (GO lang limition)

Windows credential must use git-credential-winstore - [GIT CREDENTIAL ON WIN XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693074/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command)

I hope this will help anyone needs to use XP

Answer (score 0):

For Self-hosted Windows agents, currently supported Windows OS versions:

- **Client OS:** Windows **`7`**, **`8.1`**, or **`10`**
- **Server OS:** Windows **`2008 R2 SP1`** or higher

Windows XP is no longer supported as the host of agents.

To view more details, you can see "[**Self-hosted Windows agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops-2020#check-prerequisites)".

Comment: i read the documents , is there no way override or install the agent with less options - no reporting just start/stop build script?

Comment: Hi @galsi, The Azure Pipelines build agents are firstly based on the OS, not just based on whether the build feature (and other features) can be available on the OS.

During the installation of the agent, it will check the OS information of the host machine.

Now, the Windows XP is no longer supported on Azure Pipelines. This means that even the most basic installation can not be completed, let alone use the agent.