# git: 'credential-chache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I was just wanted to get rid of this error message. After many attempts of saving my credential using

```
`git config --global credential.helper cache`
```

and other

`credential.helper`

method, I decided to use

```
`ssh keypair authentication`
```

to automatically log into my GitHub account. I successfully generated and added ssh key to my GitHub account, But whenever I'm using

```
`git pull`
```

or

```
`git push`
```

or any command that interact with github server this line

```
`git: 'credential-chache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`
```

is printed unnecessarily, although these commands run successfully without asking username or password.

is there any way to get rid of this message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693074/git-credential-cache-is-not-a-git-command)

Comment: chache? or cache? (_chache_ sounds like _chacha_ in spanish, which is an informal term for maid=

Comment: actually, When I used this command very first time, It was mistakenly entered as "chache",but in later commands I used the right one, "cache".

Comment: the link provide in "git: credential-cache is not a git command" by @meshkati dosen't solve the problem.
and I have tried that command earlier too.