# Receiving the following error when pushing commitments to Github in R: error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory fatal:

Tags: r, git, github, github-for-mac

I want to push some changes to my GitHub repository and I receive the following error, which I have been trying to solve for the last couple of hours.

```
error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

What I have just done is

- Open a new repository on Github
- Go to code and copy the https link
- Go to R Studio > New Project > Version Control > Git
- Paste the https link to repository URL
- Write some code and save it to an R file
- Select the file > Commit > and Push

and I receive this error, which I was not getting previously. (Note that I took a long break and during this time I have not committed anything to Github but previously, I have not face any error like that.)

I have searched some solution on the internet, while some suggested to use SSH key instead of https, I could not find a neat solution (that might be because I am not familiar with the Github workflow)

Therefore, I would appreciate if you can just provide me a clean solution on how to solve this problem. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

PS: I am using a Mac if that would matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should be linked to the lack of credential helper which means Git is trying to read credentials from your terminal, since it exhausted other options.

Check your `git config --global credential.helper` first.

Try and [install GCM](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/release/docs/install.md), the Git Credential Manager (which is [no longer GCM-core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309)).
And reference it in your config:

```
git config credential.helper manager
```