# git pull with password on command line in bash

Tags: git, bash, passwords, credentials, git-pull

I want to update many repos with a loop in bash:

```
for dir in *; do ( cd $dir; git pull origin master ); done
```

Although there are many similar questions as

- [How to enter command with password for git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull)
- [How to input password to git pull command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629107/how-to-input-password-to-git-pull-command)
- [How to provide username and password when run “git clone git@remote.git”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

git just allows to set credentials by

- modifying the remote repo: http://:@host/...
- using [gitcredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191985/git-http-securely-remember-credentials/12938677#12938677)

Why is there no "`--password`" option as e.g. in mysql command line?
This would help a lot for automating git tasks on the fly.

Is that a planned git feature and already on the roadmap or do we have to stick with the option given today for a long time?

Is there a workaround to specify the password e.g. using piping mechanisms?

Answer (score 1):

Because password would be stored in your `history` (type `history` in your cmd) and would be easy to steal. You want to store password in plaintext.

Comment: I know this and this is ok. Our deployment credentials are wellknown in the team and we use commands like this in mysql cli interface, too.