# get latest code from github with powershell

Tags: android, powershell, github, build

I am creating a nightly build powershell script for an android app.  It will behave like this:

1. Get latest code from github
2. build the android .apk file
3. copy that apk file into a builds folder

This script will be run every night by a windows scheduled task.

I'm having trouble with automatically getting the latest code.  I am being prompted for credentials.  How can I write a nightly build script that includes my credentials so that I dont have type them in every single time?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `_netrc` file in `C:\Users\Ben` with your credentials in it:

```
machine github.com
login yourGitHUbLogin
password yourGitHubPassword
```

See "[Git - How to use `.netrc` file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/6309)".

If the idea of leaving your credential in plain text doesn't seem a good one, you can [encrypt that file with gpg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16164673/6309).

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Although, in that link there seems to be an even easier way which is to just use this tool:  https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/103679