# Easy way to have 2 GitHub profiles on my computer?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a personal account and a work account on github, and I want to be able to push and pull to whichever I want.

Github won't let me use the same SSH key for both accounts, so how should I play this?

If I try to generate another SSH key, it either overwrites the old one, or doesn't create a new one - should I just save it, say, to ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 ?

And will I need to change the username and email in my .gitconfig file every time I want to switch users, or could I have multiple users defined in there?

To put it simply, what's the best (or any!) way to manage multiple github accounts from the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

http://mherman.org/blog/2013/09/16/managing-multiple-github-accounts/

This blog post does a great job of detailing a way to manage both accounts.

Basically, you'll create an ssh config file and switch between them with `ssh -T <profileName>`

You'll need to store the keys in seperate files, however.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach is to use https url, which allows you to specify which account you want to use for a given repo remote url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<reponame>
```

With the [netrc credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/6309), you can store the password (or [access token, if you are using the 2fa](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/)) for each account, which allows you to never enter them.
And [you can encrypt those passwords too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16164673/6309).

Don't forget to set the right `user.name` and `user.email` for each local clone.
Or you can [manage those settings with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552116/6309).