# Supplying a password to Git in a Bash script

Tags: git, bash

From a Bash script I would like to supply a password. I have tried the following:

```
echo 'mypass' | git pull

git pull < 'mypass'

git pull < echo 'mypass'
```

None seem to work.

Comment: Quick question: why?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous it is for an automatic deploy script for the app tester.  There is a lot more in the script than simply pulling code from the repo.

Comment: @jax, wonder if you could finally find a solution.

Comment: Can't remember how now.  I think I did find a way though.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602613/1803897) contains a sample bash script that works with git's credential API.

Answer (score 16):

1. Create file `git_password.sh` with content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec echo "$GIT_PASSWORD"
   ```
2. Assign your password to the GIT_PASSWORD environment variable

   ```
   $ GIT_PASSWORD=your_password
   ```
3. Execute git command with GIT_ASKPASS environment variable. It will force password prompt and execute git_password.sh as callback:

   ```
   $ GIT_ASKPASS=./git_password.sh git clone $REPO
   ```

Comment: It is only simple solution when you need to clone repository from shell script, because you have no git environment in the current folder yet.

Comment: You can also use parameter `-c "core.askPass=/path/askpass.sh"`.

Comment: Running the same in Python:  `subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', '-c', 'core.askPass='+ROOT_PATH+'\git_password.sh', 'https://username@url_to_git_repo.git'])`

Answer (score 9):

[`gitcredentials`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html) is the answer:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Git will sometimes need credentials from the user in order to perform operations; for example, it may need to ask for a username and password in order to access a remote repository over HTTP. This manual describes the mechanisms Git uses to request these credentials, as well as some features to avoid inputting these credentials repeatedly.

[...]

> **REQUESTING CREDENTIALS**
>
> Without any credential helpers defined, Git will try the following strategies to ask the user for usernames and passwords:
>
> 1. If the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, the program specified by the variable is invoked. A suitable prompt is provided to the program on the command line, and the user’s input is read from its standard output.
> 2. Otherwise, if the `core.askPass` configuration variable is set, its value is used as above.
> 3. Otherwise, if the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, its value is used as above.
> 4. Otherwise, the user is prompted on the terminal.

[...]

> Credential helpers, on the other hand, are external programs from which Git can request both usernames and passwords; they typically interface with secure storage provided by the OS or other programs.
>
> You may also have third-party helpers installed; search for `credential-*` in the output of `git help -a`, and consult the documentation of individual helpers. Once you have selected a helper, you can tell Git to use it by putting its name into the `credential.helper` variable.

`git help -a | grep credential-*` shows the following helper:

```
  credential                remote
  credential-cache          remote-ext
  credential-cache--daemon  remote-fd
  credential-osxkeychain    remote-ftp
  credential-store          remote-ftps
```

Comment: `git help -a | grep credentials-*` should be `git help -a | grep credential-*`

Comment: @Cpt.Senkfuss Thx for correction. I fixed the answer.

Comment: To set `core.askPass` use `git config --global core.askPass "new-value"`. To view the config value use `git config --global core.askPass` (without new value). Note that instead of `--global`, there is also `--system` scope (and `--local` scope, but only after a repo has been cloned).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to include the password in the definition of your remote like so:

```
https://user:password@server
```

Like this you do not need to provide it for each pull.

(Much like the solution suggested in *[How do I provide a username and password when running “git clone git@remote.git”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)*.)

**Warning:** A better approach would be to use SSH instead of HTTPS and store your public key with GitHub. Because credentials in the remote url might land in the command history, scripts or configuration files and can then be seen by others.

Comment: should this be dangerous? password saved in git log?

Comment: The URL (incl. password) will be stored in plain text in `.git/config` as remote URL. Thus, everyone with access to the cloned repo will be able to see the password. Furthermore, this URL is likely to be sent over the network again to initiate connection with the remote. Overall, this approach is the least secure.

Answer (score 2):

The main techniques for feeding an input to a Bash scripts are at *"[Automatically enter input in command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/338857/5470)"*:

```
echo 'mypass' | git pull
# or
printf 'mypass\n' | git pull
```

Since Git 1.8.3, I prefer using a **[Git credential netrc helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16164673/6309)** which will fetch and feed the right password for me.

---

Since Git 2.x, a git credential helper is preferable.
The most recent one (2022) is Microsoft (but cross-platform) [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309).

Its documentation now mentions *tokens* in addition of password, with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022):

See [commit 54e95b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54e95b466334e8f6ba4421991cfc189e1291ea87) (08 Nov 2022) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit dc8be39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc8be3971cbcd1ba47b476548e309493c0f9300c), 14 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation/gitcredentials.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54e95b466334e8f6ba4421991cfc189e1291ea87): mention password alternatives
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Git asks for a "password", but the user might use a personal access token or OAuth access token instead.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Password for 'https://AzureDiamond@github.com':
> ```

`gitcredentials` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54e95b466334e8f6ba4421991cfc189e1291ea87/Documentation/gitcredentials.txt#L20-L23):

> Git will sometimes need credentials from the user in order to perform
> operations; for example, it may need to ask for a username and password in order to access a remote repository over HTTP.
>
> **Some remotes accept a personal access token or OAuth access token as a password.**
>
> This
> manual describes the mechanisms Git uses to request these credentials,
> as well as some features to avoid inputting these credentials repeatedly.

---

Note that with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), credentials can be also *generated*, not just cached.

See [commit dabb9d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dabb9d875f665ec5da9ae8c84fed765cf9187463) (12 Nov 2022) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c197977](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c197977cb6b250906dbe1a05f899c65bb1ac2a9f), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dabb9d875f665ec5da9ae8c84fed765cf9187463): describe how a credential-generating helper works
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Previously the docs only described storage helpers.
>
> A concrete example: Git Credential Manager can generate credentials for GitHub and GitLab via OAuth.
> https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager

`gitcredentials` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dabb9d875f665ec5da9ae8c84fed765cf9187463/Documentation/gitcredentials.txt#L64-L66):

> storage provided by the OS or other programs. Alternatively, a
> credential-generating helper might generate credentials for certain servers via
> some API.

`gitcredentials` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dabb9d875f665ec5da9ae8c84fed765cf9187463/Documentation/gitcredentials.txt#L291-L292):

> If it does not support the requested operation (e.g., a read-only store or generator), it should silently ignore the request.

Comment: I think think the `\n` may be what I was missing.  The password may have entered but the enter key was never pressed, thus is never executed.  I will need to try this on Monday.

Comment: Using `printf 'mypass\n' | git pull` didn't work after all.

Comment: @jax What OS, bash and git version are you using?

Comment: Fedora 20 with default bash

Comment: Not sure what git version but probably the latest available from the repo

Comment: @jax What git version do you have on this fedora? Type git --version

Comment: I will have to tell you tomorrow of the exact versions

Comment: I will try that out tomorrow, I don't have access to the PC right now.