# Where to store my Git personal access token?

Tags: git, access-token

Is it necessary to store the personal access token somewhere locally on the machine after generating it in GitHub?

If yes, is there any preferred way where it could be stored?

Comment: Treat your tokens like passwords and keep them secret. When working with the API, use tokens as environment variables instead of hardcoding them into your programs. See number 8 from the official docs: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Comment: Exactly, I saw that comment when generating the access token, but I was not sure how people keep them safe in practice.

Comment: This seems so strange to me. Half the point of passwords is that (ideally) you memorise them and the system hashes them, so therefore they're never stored anywhere in plain text. Yet GitHub's personal access token system seems to basically force you to store the token in plain text?

Comment: May I ask - why do you need to store them? Maybe there are alternatives that do not require you to store them locally...

Comment: They are auto generated and long, so memorising them is not an option.

Comment: There seems to be a more up-to-date variant of that referenced by @bytestorm:

`sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev`;
`cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret`;
`sudo make`;
`git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`;

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/7020378

Comment: It seems GitHub just disabled password authentication for `git push` and now enforces using a token instead. So now we have to store the token in plain text or use a credential helper to store it for you. In any case, a person accessing your computer now has write access to your repo. - Back when I could just use a password that I have to enter every time, this particular security risk did not exist. And let's not forget that someone who knows my password could easily use that to create their own tokens. So in terms of security we don't gain anything, unless GitHub also decides to enforce 2FA.

Comment: @Forivin You could create a custom credential management script that stores your password using whatever encryption algorithm you prefer.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. Then the attacker can decide if he gets my GitHub password to create a new token or if he gets my credetial manager password. Everything I gained is a new attack vector compared to when I didn't have to use tokens.

Comment: Maybe I should write a custom push script that asks for my github user+password, uses it to log into my acc and creates a new token every time before doing a git push. The fact that this is possible shows how absurd the token enforcement is.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

> Half the point of passwords is that (ideally) you memorize them and the system hashes them, so therefore they're never stored anywhere in plain text.
> Yet GitHub's personal access token system seems to basically force you to store the token in plain text?

First, a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) is not a simple password, but an equivalent that:

- you can generate multiple time (for instance, one per machine from which you need to access GitHub repository)
- you can *revoke* at any time (from the GitHub web interface), which makes that PAT obsolete, even if it lingers around on one of those machines.

That differs from your password, which is unique to your account, and cannot be easily changed without having to *also* modify it everywhere you happen to use it.

---

Since a PAT can be used in place of a password when performing Git operations over HTTPS with Git on the command line or the API, you can use a [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) to cache it securely.
On Windows, for instance, that would use [the Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838624/6309), through the [GCM -- Git Credential Manager -- for Windows, Mac or Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core):

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
# Git 2.39+
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

(manager-core is being replaced by/renamed as [**manager** for Git 2.39+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309), Q4 2022)

The first time you are pushing to a repo, a popup will ask for your credentials: username *and* your PAT.
The next time, it won't ask, and reuse directly that PAT, which remains stored securely in your Credential Manager.

A similar idea applies for [Mac with the OSX keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/), and Linux with the [GNOME Keyring](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/11/21/gnome-keyring-git-credential-helper/) (in 2021, it would [need a DBus session and `libsecret`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115243/6309)), but in 2021, GCM-Core covers those use cases.
The idea remains: store the PAT in an *encrypted* credentials store.

---

As mentioned above, the more modern solution (Q4 2020) is [Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/), or, Q4 2022, [Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager)

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
# Git 2.39+:
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

---

Before Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), for Linux:

You need for that to install `git-credential-manager-core`, downloading its [latest release](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/), like [`gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.474.41365.deb`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/download/v2.0.474/gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.474.41365.deb)

```
sudo dpkg -i <path-to-package>
git-credential-manager-core configure
```

Although, with GCM (Git-Credential-Manager-Core) on Linux, as noted by [Mekky Mayata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11813914/mekky-mayata) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645843/where-to-store-the-personal-access-token-from-github/51505417?noredirect=1#comment118110559_51505417), you need to define a `git config --global credential.credentialStore` first.

See "[**Credential stores on Linux**](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/credstores.md)":

> There are four options for storing credentials that Git Credential Manager (GCM) manages on Linux platforms:
>
> - [freedesktop.org Secret Service API](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/)
> - GPG/[`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/) compatible files
> - Git's built-in [credential cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)
> - Plaintext files
>
> By default, GCM comes *not* configured.
> You can select which credential store to use by setting the `GCM_CREDENTIAL_STORE` environment variable, or the `credential.credentialStore` Git configuration setting.

As noted by [agent18](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986651/agent18) in [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/5470), using `git-credential-libsecret` after installing `libsecret-1-0` and `libsecret-1-dev` is a good first step.
But, again, that should be now wrapped by `credential-manager-core` (before Git 2.39).

Comment: The GNOME Keyring solution you linked does not work for Ubuntu 20.04, as [the libgnome-keyring-dev package is not available in that suite](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgnome-keyring-dev). Is this what you meant by Linux support is not fully implemented yet? What recommended workarounds are there, and where can I check the progress being made?

Comment: @Mxt The GCM-Core does support now Linux (https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/master/docs/linuxcredstores.md), do it is now the official workaround.

Comment: The last two lines give me the following error after `git push`:
`/var/tmp/.net/user/git-credential-manager-core/unqypyc0.awl/git-credential-manager-core get: 1: /var/tmp/.net/user/git-credential-manager-core/unqypyc0.awl/git-credential-manager-core: not found`

Comment: @IlyaPalachev Do you have installed `git-credential-manager-core`? Is it in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Yes: `$ dpkg -l | grep gcm` gives me 
`ii  gcmcore                                    2.0.318.44100                       amd64`

Comment: @IlyaPalachev Do you find `git-credential-manager-core` anywhere on your system?

Comment: @VonC I have it with ".dll" extension: `/var/tmp/.net/user/git-credential-manager-core/unqypyc0.awl/git-credential-manager-core.dll`

Comment: @IlyaPalachev Did you install a Windows version?

Comment: @VonC I downloaded GCM Linux deb package from  official GCM GitHub releases page, [gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.318.44100.deb](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/download/v2.0.318-beta/gcmcore-linux_amd64.2.0.318.44100.deb) - I used `wget` to download and `dpkg -i` to install.

Comment: @VonC So, should I create an issue on GCM repository for that?

Comment: @IlyaPalachev yes, creating an issue is a good idea: let me know of the issue number, I will follow it.

Comment: upon running the above commands on Linux, it worked fine but I got "fatal: No credential backing store has been selected." solved this by editing the git config file `git config -e --global` and adding a credentialStore value (plaintext, gpg, secretservice) to it. 
thanks @VonC

Comment: @Mekky_Mayata Good point. I have edited the answer to make that step more visible for Linux, adding the relevant documentation.

Comment: But that cache will only work for 600 seconds (by default) and then if we forget it we have to re-generate a new token which doesn't make sense! Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @aderchox I thought it was 900, not 600: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache#Documentation/git-credential-cache.txt---timeoutltsecondsgt. And you would then need to enter the same token again. An expired cache does not invalidate an existing PAT.

Comment: @VonC I was wrong it's 900. Thank you. Yes of course, I know that the PAT will not be affected by the cache, what's strange is that it's not a real solution to be used by humans. Maybe if it's an app it makes sense, but I won't remember such a token and I won't even save it somewhere on my computer because that's very inconvenient and slow to have to copy paste it all the time. In my opinion using ssh keys is the only good solution if GitHub is going to not allow the passwords.

Comment: @aderchox If you use the Git Credential Manager Core (and a cache `credential.credentialStore`), I don't think the default timeout would apply though. I need to test that.

Comment: Please look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/443958) for stellar instructions on how to "store" the PAT securely and work with the git workflow.

Comment: @agent18 Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Hi @VonC, I didn't use the "Credential manager" I think. I don't understand them. I have detailed my answer below. Please do have a look and improve it if you can.

Comment: @agent18 It is "manager-core", not "manager". And it will wrap whatever secret manager is used by the underlying OS. For Linux: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/135#issuecomment-645877323

Comment: This SO link provided the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration

Comment: @yellowjacket05 Thank you. I have edited the answer to include a link to the post you mention. But the right solution in 2021 is the one I detail above: `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`, with, on Linux, an additional `credential.credentialStore` configured. It does work well and is a cross-platform credential helper.

Comment: still not convinced why PAT in this form have to be used by everyone. Why not allow multiple passwords and make them revocable. Or let users create a PAT instead of using random strings. life would much easier.

Comment: @volkit A password cannot be rescinded like a PAT can. And don't forget the PAT format has recently changed (I had to regenerate mine recently): https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-04-authentication-token-format-updates/

Comment: So, basically, If I lose my secret token, I can any time login to the web interface using my password and generate a new token ?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @VonC thank you, I am relieved ! ;) Thought I can't access my GitHub account anymore if I lose that token …

Comment: broken link @ "Credential Stores on Linux" : 
linuxcredstores.md moved to credstores.md

Comment: @rclyde Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly and restored the link.

Comment: I think the answer could be simplified

Comment: git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @trueToastedCode It will be, if your PATH (%PATH%? $PATH? What is your OS) includes /path/to/git/mingw64/bin. Note that `manager-core` is being [deprecated and replaced with `manager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309).

Comment: what about when using _PAT_ in github workflows? where to store it? hard-coded in the `.yml` file?

Comment: @JobaDiniz First, check if you actually need a PAT, considering a GitHub workflow would have an automatic token authentication, through the [`GITHUB_TOKEN` secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

Answer (score 270):

In my case, in Ubuntu, the accepted solution didn't work with a message like

> git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command

but `store` instead of `manager` worked well:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Note that you will be prompted to introduce your credentials again the next time you use git before the credential manager saves them.

Comment: Just to add a note to this - after enabling this you will be prompted for your creds on your next commit. After that, they are stored.

Comment: This seems to store your token in plain text in ~/.git-credentials

Comment: I find it really helpful when people provide atleast a link after making a warning about something. Please look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/443958) for stellar instructions on how to "store" the PAT securely and work with the git workflow. Just 3 lines of code.

Comment: Just a quick tip, remove --global if you want this configuration for only a specific repo

Comment: After lots of messing around I ended up using github's ssh instead of http (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Comment: What this does is that it sets up Git to store the personal access token next time you push it, so it's normal if it doesn't ask for the personal access token directly. Next time you push you will still have to specify the personal access token, but the times after that you won't.

Answer (score 48):

Alternatively, you can create a `~/.netrc` file in home directory and save your login credentials to it.

```
cat ~/.netrc
machine github.com login <login-id> password <token-password>
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: This works like a charm and is very practical. +1. And to me, the answer is clear enough.

Comment: Excellent!! It worked great. Can you please add little more explanation what going behind.

Comment: This is a goddamn arcane wizardy. How does it exactly work? Is it safe?

Comment: On executing the command, cat ~/.netrc                                                                     
Receiving this error,  'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Details of netrc file and its link with inetutils are explained in this link.  
https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html

Comment: @JwalaKumar just create a file in your linux home directory with name `.netrc` and have the contents as shown in the answer.

If you are using windows then please try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password

Comment: @blahblah libcurl supports the older and deprecated netrc standard. Since git is linked to libcurl its able to make http, smtp, and ftp requests using one's `.netrc`. The syntax is well documented.

But one does not use it because its a flat file that even with `0600` perms sits on the filesystem with passwords in clear text that *every* process ran as that user can abutraily read.

Comment: while clever use of libcurl's support for netrc. down voted for reasons above.

Comment: Excellent!! It worked great with git and github.com(PAT).

Comment: Very well. I have tested it on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Its worked out well for me. Thanks a lot, it have saved my time.

Comment: This stores credentials in `~/.netrc`, which is just as good as the answer above which stores credentials in `~/.git-credentials`. Use at your own risk, but that can be handy nonetheless.

Answer (score 36):

To store your credentials in cache and avoid logging in every time you perform a git action, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to your local repository folder.
2. In the current folder's terminal: `git config --global --replace-all credential.helper cache`
3. Perform `git push` or `git pull`.
4. Login with username and access token (access token is your password). The token can be setup in GitHub and have access to repo, workflow, write:packages and delete:packages.
5. Repeat `git push` or any git action and you'll find that it doesn't ask for login credentials from now on.

Answer (score 28):

**Tested on** Ubuntu 20.04, almost fresh install, with Git 2.25.1 and unity 7.5.

**Authentication basics**

Github needs an authentication key (with certain rights tied to said authentication key). A particular auth key has certain rights, (read private repos, read write public repos etc...) and "acts as a password" coupled with rights which can be revoked whenever the user wants.

**Personal Access Token**

1. We start with making a [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token). I.E., Settings --> Developer Settings--> Persaonl access tokens --> Generate new token --> Note --> set permissions (repo,repo_hook maybe) --> generate token
2. `git push` the repo and type the generated token(very long password) as password when asked.

**Storing the password in different ways**

3. - Can be done in a file and then using `xclip` to bring it back to clipboard and paste it everytime (Screw this)
   - Cache with the [help of git commands](http://gmacario.github.io/2017/08/08/cmdline-git-with-github-2fa.html) `git config credential.helper cache <time-limit-of-cache>`. But you still have to somehow clipboard the password after the timelimit.
   - Store it permanently in a file [with git commands](http://gmacario.github.io/2017/08/08/cmdline-git-with-github-2fa.html) `git config credential.helper store` (don't use --global). This is NOT ENCRYPTED. You can open the file and read it. (e.g., If someone gets access to your laptop they can pretty much read the Password using a bootable USB (assuming your whole system is not encrypted)).
   - Or go the encryption route as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/443958). It is not complicated at all. 3 simple steps.

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
    
git config credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

This allows to store the password/personal access token in an encrypted format. The `git config` file can be found in the `.git/config` file in your loca repo as shown [here](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved), if you ever need it.

P.S.
There are many places that suggest the use of [Gnome-keyring](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/11/21/gnome-keyring-git-credential-helper/) but that is apparently [deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/443958).

**Storing passwords/PATs for more than one account**

This becomes tricky and it appears as @VonC suggests that we need a `Git-Credential-Manager core` (GCM core). This answer is enhanced based on my findings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406012/5986651).

1. First [install GCM core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406012/5986651)

   1. Download [latest .deb package](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/tag/v2.0.394-beta)
   2. `sudo dpkg -i <path-to-package>`
   3. `git-credential-manager-core configure`
   4. `git config --global credential.credentialStore secretservice` as we use `libsecret`
2. Get latest git

   In my case I had git 2.25 and got error `error: unknown option 'show-scope'`. It appears that GCM core is using higher git
   (atleast 2.26).

   So install the latest and greatest `git` as per [here](http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/):

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    apt list git # shows the latest git currently 2.31
    sudo apt-get install git #or sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Update git remote path with username built in

   GCM core needs this to identify the different accounts.:(

   ```
    git remote set-url origin https://user1@github.com/user1/myRepo1.git
    git remote set-url origin https://user2@github.com/user1/myRepo1.git
                                  ^^^^^
   ```

Your `~/.gitconfig` file will thus have the following :

```
[credential]
   helper = /usr/bin/git-credential-manager-core
   credentialStore = secretservice
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
   useHttpPath = true
```

Comment: I had to use `git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret erase` before and then save the new token. I was already using libsecret

Comment: Your answer was useful, but so much drama. This was all I did `git remote set-url origin https://username:your-personal-access-token@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: @iKev61 So, you stored your password in a configuration file?

Comment: @9pfssupportsUkraine no password was used

Answer (score 6):

I like to keep them encrypted within the repository and load them using `.envrc` (https://direnv.net/)

For doing this I use [ssh-vault](https://ssh-vault.com/) to encrypt the data  using my [ssh keys that GitHub already is exposing](https://github.com/foo.keys), for example:

```
echo MY_TOKEN="secret" | ssh-vault -u <github-user> create > my-encypted-vars.ssh
```

Then the content of `.envrc` looks something like this:

```
echo "Enter ssh key password"
context=$(ssh-vault view $HOME/projects/my-encrypted.ssh | tail -n +2)
export ${context}
```

This will decrypt the data in `my-encrypted-vars.ssh` file and set `MY_TOKEN` into my environment variables every time I `cd` into the project dir.

By doing this tokens/variables are stored "safely" and always ready to use as environment variables

Comment: I prefer using official credential stores, as I explain [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/6309), but your proposition of a dedicated vault is interesting. +1

Comment: I would recommend putting `my-encrypted-vars.ssh` in `.git` to avoid checking it in into source

Answer (score 6):

try enabling this to help with persisting across push / pulls

```
git config credential.helper store
```

For ongoing cloning of repo / for macOS users / install iTerm2
https://iterm2.com/

[image]

Enable Toolbelt

[image]

Just click the snippet whenever you need it.
P.S. you are using oh-my-zsh, aren't you?
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh

Answer (score 5):

Use git **insteadOf**. Basically replace every https://github call with your access tokens + https://

`git config --global url."https://<username>:<github-token>@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/`

Now every call to github will automatically be appended with your credentials.

I found this great answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55227275/7018871).
Some more info about [git insteadOf](https://gist.github.com/Kovrinic/ea5e7123ab5c97d451804ea222ecd78a).

Answer (score 4):

You can cache your credentials for a defined time using:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

The default cache period is 900 sec (15 min) but can be changed with:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

See the following Github page:

> https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

This is not a permanent store and as per other comments credentials should not be stored in plain text, which is a security risk. I use a password manager (https://bitwarden.com/) to store the [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) then copy it in for the first use, where it is then cached.  A PAT is required if you enable 2FA on your Github account.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to save the token *somewhere*, when you don't want to type it each time your app asks for it :-)

A good solution is using environment variables, as already suggested in [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645843/where-to-store-the-personal-access-token-from-github#comment80240852_46645843).

But you still have to set the environment variable somewhere.
On Windows (which I'm using), you could use the [dialog box](https://serverfault.com/q/351129/1747)  in the system settings *(I don't know if other operating systems have something similar)*.

I don't do this, I prefer a script in my project.
In a private project, you *may* commit this to source control, but this is a matter of preference.

In one of my personal projects, I'm calling the GitHub API as well, using a personal access token.
It's a command line app and the end user will save the token in a config file *(which is OK)*.

But I need the token for development as well, because the project has integration tests where I'm calling the GitHub API.

And that project is public on GitHub, so I couldn't save the token in source control.

What I did is this:

- I have a batch file *(remember, I'm on Windows)* called `environment-variables.bat` which sets all required environment variables including the access token
- I'm calling this in my [build script](https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/blob/6beae943690f0dd9ff5ea120742f7dd19e250df8/build-release.bat) and in the [batch file](https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/blob/6beae943690f0dd9ff5ea120742f7dd19e250df8/run-all-tests.bat) I'm using to run my tests
- `environment-variables.bat` is [ignored in source control](https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/blob/6beae943690f0dd9ff5ea120742f7dd19e250df8/.gitignore#L8)
- But in source control, there's [`environment-variables.bat.sample`](https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/blob/6beae943690f0dd9ff5ea120742f7dd19e250df8/environment-variables.bat.sample) instead, which contains the same, but a fake token/password.

So I can just rename this file to `environment-variables.bat`, replace the fake password by the real one, and everything works.

---

This is not the perfect solution for all cases, though.

In my project, I have the problem that I need to use more tokens/passwords for more APIs in the future.

So the number of tokens in my `environment-variables.bat` **will** increase, making it difficult for potential contributors to actually execute all integration tests. And I still [don't know how to deal with that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/343013/3826).

Answer (score 2):

In my use case, I store the PAT in a password manager, e.g. LastPass, KeePass, 1Password.  When I need it in a Linux environment ( e.g. Docker ), I save the PAT in an environment variable and then use git's credential helper setting.  For example:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 600'

<< eof tr -d ' ' | git credential-cache store 
  protocol=https
  host=github.com
  username=nonce
  password=${GITHUB_PAT}
eof
```

With a PAT the username can be anything except blank.  Here's a gist that elaborates:

https://gist.github.com/rwcitek/da862e9e27cc28d3e96e62a2ca4b2b64

Answer (score 1):

You can store the [github https token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

Two alternatives to map a git host to a pass entry:

- bash script to map to the right `pass` entry:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# assuming "get" action from git and a config like this
# git config --global credential.helper $XDG_BIN_HOME'/git_credentials_from_pass $@'
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" =~ host=.*github.com.* ]]; then
      echo "username=your_user_name"
      echo "password=$(pass show token_github.com/your_username)"
  #else ...
  fi
done
```

Change `your_username` and `token_github.com` the way you set it up with `pass insert`.

This adds the token to `pass` without typing or pasting twice:

```sh
echo your_github_token | sed p | pass add token_github.com/your_username
```

- Install [pass-git-helper](https://github.com/rpuntaie/pass-git-helper) and:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper '!pass-git-helper $@'
```

`pass-git-helper` needs an ini-file to map between the `git` request and the `pass` entry.
`${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/pass-git-helper/git-pass-mapping.ini` example:

```
[DEFAULT]
username_extractor=entry_name
[github.com*]
target=token_${host}/your_github_username
```

Comment: Actually this is a great answer! way better than the .netrc one. Downsides it's a linux/macos only solution. But windows has its own cred store anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
```

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null
```

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gh
gh auth login
```

> it will ask to enter the protocol and token

Then I clones the repo again . Its not asking for token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For Storing PAT you can use [gh library](https://github.com/cli/cli)

Installation

`conda install -c conda-forge gh -y`

Once the installation is complete, type this command:

```
gh auth login
```

```
Use the arrow and enter keys to navigate a series of prompts.

What account do you want to log into?

    > Github.com
      GitHub Enterprise Server

What is your preferred protocol for Git operations?

    > HTTPS
      SSH

Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials? (Y/n)

How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI?

      Login with a web browser
    > Paste an authentication token
```

Now you’ve added your token — this will make pulling and pushing code a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Install Git Credential Manager! https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager . GCM supports caching as well as a variety of platform-specific credential stores that persist between sessions.

Even better: GCM supports user-friendly secure authentication to GitHub and GitLab via web browser with OAuth. This means you no longer even need to create personal access tokens. When you git push, simply follow a link to GitHub and authorize the app. Subsequent authentications require no interaction.

OAuth is *more* secure than personal access tokens, because the tokens have short expiry, refreshed when required using longer-lived refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I resort to an unorthodox solution.

I have saved it in my Telegram `Saved Messages`. Every time one expires, I create a new one and edit the message. I feel It's secure, as long as I don't lose access to my Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way on windows is to:

1. try to clone a private repository,
2. (as of 2024) git will produce a pop up that asks you to sign in your device or use an access code
3. select access code,
4. then paste in your token and
5. hit enter.

That's an **extremely** simple way to get git/windows to remember your GitHub personal access token!

Answer (score -1):

Basically I did this on my machine:

> https://gist.github.com/bsara/5c4d90db3016814a3d2fe38d314f9c23

My profile script is slightly different than described:

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
        . "$env" >| /dev/null ; 
}

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

Comment: downvoting; while a nice solution for ssh key access does not address OP's question for personal access tokens (aka https username:PAT pairs).