# Github, create issue on repository without requiring a github user account

Tags: git, rest, api, github, github-api

I have an electron app that has a bug reporting feature.  I would like this bug reporter to use the [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to [create an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) automatically.  Here is the catch, I don't want my users to create and use their own github account to do so.

Is it possible to use the github API to create issues, without requiring an account?

My current workaround is to simply create a 'bug reporting' account, and share that account's access token with the source code. That way, whenever anybody creates an issue it's listed under that user. Seems like a stretch, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3):

> My current workaround is to simply create a 'bug reporting' account, and share that account's access token with the source code.

That remains the simplest solution, especially using a PAT (Personal Access Token).
As I explained in "[Where to store the personal access token from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/6309)", using a PAT allows for an easy revocation if needed, without having to invalidate the account password.

Answer (score 2):

Github recently announced that in the roadmap for Q4 2020 will be RBAC, which will allow you to more easily control the access your Github users have to a greater granular level, removing the need for many 3rd party apps and giving issue-level access without access to code

More here: https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/111

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered [Git Reports](https://gitreports.com/) while searching for the same thing.

From the website:

> Git Reports is a free service that lets you set up a stable URL for anonymous users to submit bugs and other Issues to your GitHub repositories, without exposing your code, requiring users to log in with GitHub, or using a messy two-repository solution. It works with public and private repositories, and it works with personal and organization repositories.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though the link might answer the question, it is better to add consolidated details out here so that the answers stands out even if the link is broken.

Comment: Looks like this link is dead.