# How to add a GitHub personal access token to Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, access-token

I received [an email](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) saying GitHub will require token authentication after August 13 2021. I want to ensure I don't have an interruption of service (push/pull) after this date.
So I logged into GitHub and [created a token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) for my single repository.

Now I want to use the token to push/pull my repository from GitHub, in Visual Studio Code, which uses Git and the command line, which I have installed on my Mac.

What do I do to add/replace the password from GitHub with the generated token I just created to push/pull from my repository? Can I do it from Visual Studio Code or does it get added from the terminal command line?

Answer (score 144):

Follow these simple steps to set up GitHub authentication with a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token):

1. Open a command line window on your PC or Terminal on Mac
2. Set the current directory to your project root

   ```
   cd C:\Users\Giddy\source\repo\MySampleProject
   ```
3. Run the command to set remote access via a token

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://sampleuser:a7b19929***58fe65d1c@github.com/sampleuser/sampleproject.git
   ```

Comment: This got GitLab authentication working for me after 2FA was made mandatory on the repo.

Comment: `git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git` for troubleshooting `git push` worked very well. +1

Comment: I did that, and it seems to work, but it also means that the token is stored in plain text in the git config file. Surely that's not a good idea?

Comment: and it (the token) will be sent directly in the url request, which is also not very cool.

Comment: Works on vscode in ubuntu as wel.

Answer (score 60):

Tested on Visual Studio Code (Mac)

> no need for an extra extension. I only trust official extensions, sorry.
> GitHub extension by KnisterPeter

1. Generate a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) from github.com
2. Make sure to save your access token (e.g., ghp_pVC*****)
3. Open your project with Visual Studio Code or navigate to your project in the terminal, `cd ~/path/to/your/project`
4. In the Visual Studio Code terminal, `git remote set-url origin https://<personal_access_token>@github.com/<your_username or organization_name>/<repo_name>.git`
5. Now you can try `git push`

#### Note:

When generating a personal access token, make sure to enable **workflow**:

[image]

## Hint

You can type `git remote -v` to see your origin or upstream.

```
origin  https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (push)
```

Also after setting `git remote set-url origin https://<personal_access_token>@github.com/<your_username>/<repo_name>.git`

Your `git remote -v` should be something like:

```
origin  https://<your_personal_access_token>@github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  https://<your_personal_access_token>@github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git (push)
```

Comment: Good answer @sultanmyrza thanks!
Just to add before step 3, you must make sure you are in the directory that holds the files you are going to commit (use cd command as appropriate)

Comment: @JoseRondon noted, updated 

Comment: Still asking me for a password. Running on Ubuntu but that should make no difference, it doesn't work.

Comment: With our gitlab repo, I was finally able to get it to work, here is sanitized example: `git remote set-url origin https://<pat>@code.ini.uzh.ch/CoACH/CoACH-labs.git`.  <pat> is the personal access token. Note there is no username (the PAT is the username).  And note that it specifies https connection but uses the .git form of the connection.

Answer (score 17):

If you get a message like this using the [**GitHub extension by KnisterPeter**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KnisterPeter.vscode-github):

> To enable the Visual Studio Code GitHub Support, please set a Personal Access Token
>
> [image: Enable Visual Studio Code GitHub Support]

1. Go to *Settings* → *Developer Settings* → *Personal Access Token*

   Or go directly to *https://github.com/settings/tokens*
2. Click **Generate New Token**

   [image: Settings -> Generate New Token]
3. Go back to Visual Studio Code and open the *Command Palette* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
4. Type in **GitHub: Set Personal Access Token**

   [image: Set Personal Access Token]
5. Paste in the value from your newly generated token

Comment: "No matching commands" when searching for "Github: Set Personal Access Token"

Comment: @AmarIlindra - you'll need the [Github extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KnisterPeter.vscode-github) installed - if you have it installed, and still don't see it, I'd file an issue there

Comment: @KyleMit That is not an official extension

Comment: @mr.loop, sure, but it's a common one that might have brought people to this Q&A anyway since it has the same debug error message

Comment: Not trusting a third party with my access tokens. That's just bad form.

Comment: This extension is deprecated in favour of [Github Pull Requests and Issues] (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github). As noted by KnisterPeter

Answer (score 5):

1. In Visual Studio Code, try to push or pull from the remote repository
2. Click the 'Signing into GitHub' message at the bottom of Visual Studio Code
3. Click 'Allow' in the prompt
4. Enter the token in the prompt that appears at the top of Visual Studio Code

To see the output related to GitHub authentication:

1. Open a terminal in Visual Studio Code
2. Click 'Output' at the top of the terminal panel
3. Click 'GitHub Authentication' from the drop down menu

At the time of writing, I'm on Visual Studio Code v1.56.0.

Comment: Had a different flow after the 1st step, but similar overall (VSCode v1.56.1, Windows). Got confused by the auth prompt asking for a "password" when it really wanted the the token though (I entered my GitHub password at first)

Comment: i get no such prompt

Comment: when I try 'git push', I never see 'Signing into GitHub' message, all I see is 'remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ivanpartizan/algorithms.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403'

I created my Personal Access Token, but how can I use it???

Comment: @ivanmilenkovic see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830126/7896203 it fixed this for me

Answer (score 5):

Copy the following line and paste it into your Visual Studio Code terminal

```
git remote set-url origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORYNAME>.git
```

Replace TOKEN with your token USERNAME with username and REPOSITORYNAME with your repository. This should work.
Your final line should look something like:

```
git remote set-url origin https://asdlkuresdflj23433423lj234@github.com/brother/sampleapp.git
```

Comment: Certainly worked for me using VSCode 1.62.2, but where is that token stored? Hopefully not in plain text.

Comment: @Karl oh it totally is, in `.git/config`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using HTTPS URLs for your remote repositories, that means you can cache your credentials: today, that would be your GitHub user account name and password, tomorrow, the password will be your token.

Check your `git config credential.helper` result.
If it is manager or manager-core, remove the old password with a `git credential-manager-core erase`
("destructive command" in that it will remote the `github.com` entry and its associated value, the password)
(a `git credential-manager-core get` would *read* that old value)

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=<yourGitHubAccountName>"|git credential-manager-core erase
```

Then `git credential-manager-core store` to store the token:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=<yourGitHubAccountName>\npassword=<newToken>"|git credential-manager-core store
```

(replace `credential-manager-core` by `credential-manager` if the credential helper is `manager` instead of `manager-core`)

Visual Studio Code will use that credential helper, with the new "password" (token) stored for the remote site.

---

If you get, on Linux:

```
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

You would need to to [download and install GCM](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#linux).

Comment: I ran your command and I see 'osxkeychain'

Comment: @user1186050 For Mac, you can replace `credential-manager-core` by  `credential-osxkeychain` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007050/6309) Or you can do it graphically: https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychaina

Comment: I ran `git config credential.helper` and got nothing..

Comment: @BenWhitmore What version of Git and OS are you using?

Comment: @VonC git 2.25.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: @BenWhitmore Is it possible to upgrade to Git 2.31.1? and then install https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core, then install libsecret and set `credential.credentialStore` to `secretservice`, as described in https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/master/docs/linuxcredstores.md#1-freedesktoporg-secret-service-api, and discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/6309.

Comment: Seems like a lot of bother. GiddyNaya's answer worked for me.

Comment: @BenWhitmore you mean putting a password or token in clear right in the URL? That is a bad idea, based on a bad answer.

Comment: On Linux ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa), but with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)). And a working Git / push to GitHub ***before*** the update to Visual Studio Code 1.62.2), for the first command line, I got `git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` and `git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`. Git version: 2.25.1

Comment: Perhaps mention in the answer if the first command is (really) destructive or not (`erase`)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Good idea. I have (actively) edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PeterMortensen And I have added the "download and install" link for GCM.

Comment: Windows cmd.exe -- https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/issues/634

Answer (score 3):

If you are not prompted for your username and password, your credentials may be cached on your computer. You can update your credentials in the Keychain to replace your old password with the token.

*[Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)*

Comment: This was my exact problem. Shutting down VS Code, removing ALL github login credentials, and restarting VS Code fixed the problem for me. I just had to re-login to turn on Settings Sync and VS Code handled all the rest

Answer (score 3):

I was on GitHub password authentication, and got hit with Visual Studio Code's "you can't use password auth for GitHub anymore".

I was on a Mac, so I had the stock Git (v2.21).

I tried these steps and can now check in code via Visual Studio Code error free (note this approach uses Microsoft Git Credential Manager Core - see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)):

1. Update Git using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)), `brew install git`. It'll create a new symbolic link on your system to Git pointing to */usr/local/bin/git*, so the Mac stock Git won't be used
2. Set up Personal Access Token with [instructions on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
3. Go into the Mac keychain and delete the `vscode.github.com` password credential
4. Install Microsoft's Git Credential Manager Core (GCMC) - [instructions on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)
5. Quit and restart Visual Studio Code, and push again. You'll be prompted to authorise GCMC in a browser. Once you do that, pushing from Visual Studio Code should work automatically as the GCMC will handle Git authorisation going forward.

Answer (score 2):

The following helped me (I am user Ubuntu 22.04):
git config --local -e
Edit your data ==>:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://YourGitlabName:YourToken@gitlab.com/YorRepo
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/main
[user]
        name = YourGitlabName
        email = YourGitlabE-mail
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33447252)

Comment: Works perfectly! Just replace **Gitlab** info with your **GitHub** info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally got the 'Signing into GitHub' prompt to appear and authenticate successfully. Basically what you need to do after getting the confirmation page below *(after you click 'Authorize Visual Studio Code' in the browser window)*:

> **Success!**
>
> Authorization was successful. You will be redirected back to Visual
> Studio Code
>
> Didn't work? If you aren't redirected, you can add the token manually.
>
> ```
>         **Your authorization token:**
> ```
>
> **vscode://vscode.github-authentication/did-authenticate?windowid=1&code=[Not-A+Real+Token)SJ###AASDf**
>
> ......... etc

---

Is switch back to VS Code *(probably already came into focus automatically)* and choose **'Do Not Prompt Again'** or whatever the message is... **THENNN you can finally see and click the prompt 'Signing into GitHub ...'**

Hopefully this helps someone... because as simple as it sounds, VS Code would not prompt when closing the prompt nor when choosing the option to 'Show Git Log'.

Comment: Please explain "and finally got the 'Signing into GitHub' prompt to appear". Obviously you had difficulty with this and should eloborate.

Comment: My issue was identical to that of the OP.

Comment: *How* did you get the 'Signing into GitHub' prompt to appear? Is that a conclusion of this answer or something you achieved first? If the latter, *how*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68823502/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I just came across this answer today. When did best practice change from being honest about adding "Update:" notes to your answer so as not to be deceptive and to have good continuity with your changes resulting from comment suggestions to what you said?

Comment: @Eric Hepperle - CodeSlayer2010: There isn't any deception when there is [a public revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66233446/revisions). See for example [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230693) and [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to solve this by signing out of GitHub then signing back in. I was getting the error "No remote repository" in Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10, when there was clearly a repository on GitHub. On the same PC, I use GitHub Desktop for python projects in Spyder, on the same GitHub account, and I was not having access errors, and I was not using Personal Access Tokens, so that pointed to an issue with the Visual Studio Connection.

Answer (score 0):

#### Auth in browser with Visual Studio Code.

###### Prerequisites

- Install the latest NuGet version.
- Install Azure Artifacts Credential Provider.

https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider

```
wget -qO- https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh | bash
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"
```

###### Inside Visual Studio Code

- open terminal (inside visual studio code)
- run `dotnet restore --interactive`
- Read carefully the prompt `[CredentialProvider]ATTENTION: User interaction required.`
- use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code `display inside the prompt` to authenticate.