# Set github personal access token in visual studio code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set the personal access token in VS code, but it doesn't seem to accept it. I put it in the "Github: Set Personal Access Token" in the command palette but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I also put the token in the Windows Credentials manager.

When I try to push, I get this error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://<usr>:token@github.com/<us>/repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: **See Also**: [How to add github personal access token to visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66231282/1366033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Git for Windows, and the `git config --global credential.helper` set to `manager-core`.

From there, check you do have indeed the token as password stored in the credential helper, using a [CMD (not git bash)](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-open-command-prompt-in-windows-10.html):

```sh
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager-core.exe" get
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=VonC
password=ghp_Dxc...<yourToken>
```

Make sure that token starts with `ghp_` (following the [new token format update](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-04-authentication-token-format-updates/)).

If not, remove it:

```sh
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager-core.exe" earase
```

Then the next push will ask and store your new credentials.
No need to manually tweak the Windows Credential Manager: that is what those helpers are for.

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236027/discussion-between-vonc-and-bill-ferster), the problem was twofold:

- The System User Windows path did not reference the Git installation path
- The remote URL registered in the local repository did include directly the token (instead of relying on the git credential manager)

Solving those two issues allowed VSCode to start pushing with the proper credentials.

Comment: I re-installed a new version of git, set the credential.helper to manager-core, there doesn't seem to be that file there:
 C:\Users/bfers/git/gitcpl>printf "protocol=https/nhost=github.com"|"C:\Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe" get
bash: C:Users/bfers/git/gitcpl: No such file or directory
fatal: Missing 'protocol' input argument. My git file is .git, and it failed when I added the dot

Comment: @BillFerster Sorry, `C:\Users\<aUsername>\git\gitcpl` was just the folder I was in when I typed the `printf/git-credential-manager-core.exe` command. You can execute it in any folder you want. But in a CMD. Not in a git bash.

Comment: My toke is indeed "ghp..." Sorry to be dense, but how would I write that file to my desktop?

Comment: @BillFerster Make sure you have remove old github.com entries (if `git-credential-manager-core.exe get` shows you old password. Then the next `git push` will prompt you for your new credentials and cache them. Use your GitHub account name and token.

Comment: @BillFerster VSCode will "know" of the token simply because it will use the same credential helper than in CLI: the manager-core.

Comment: $  git-credential-manager-core.exe get
bash: git-credential-manager-core.exe: command not found

Comment: @BillFerster bash? I remember stating in a past command: CMD only, no git bash. And use the full path of the executable in that CMD, as shown in the answer.

Comment: @BillFerster No need for VSCode terminal: let's make it right in a simple CMD. Then VSCode will work.

Comment: Failed to locate 'git.exe' executable on the path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236027/discussion-between-vonc-and-bill-ferster).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows 10, search for "Manage network passwords" - it takes you to open the Credential Manager in the Control Panel. Find `git:https://github.com` in the list (not `GitHub - https://api.github.com/username`) and change the password to the personal access token you [create on the GitHub site](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

I was able to push normally using the GitHub integration in VS Code after doing this.

Comment: there was only git://https://bferster@github.com, so I added git:https://github.com, set the token in both, but still get the same error message on push

Comment: @BillFerster No: you need to *remove* those entries, as my answer states.

Comment: I'm totally confused now. I remove both entries, but still no joy. How would vscode know the token

Comment: thanks dude, I was looking for a way to edit my personal token for 2 two days in a row

Answer (score 0):

### Are there too many cloned repositories?

##### Storing the token globally will be easy to use.

If you have a lot of cloned repositories on your machine, I think the best way is to store the Github token in git credential.helper globally.

Assuming you have a token handy and are trying to run any git command that needs authentication, even within VSCode, the steps are:

1. Enter your username;
2. Enter the previously generated token as the password in the password field;
3. Run the command to retain the token in the credential.helper cache;

Command to step 3:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

To clear the token from the local computer:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

There is a concern with credential caching related to how long the token is stored. To control this time it is necessary to set the "timeout" parameter or change the strategy to permanently store the credentials by changing the "cache" to "store" like this:

Complement command to step 3 (timeout in seconds):

```
# timeout default is 900 seconds
git config --global --set credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Command to step 3 (permanent storage):

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

**Using this helper will store your passwords/token unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions.**

Useful references:

- [Generating a new Github token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).
- [Credential](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials), [credential cache](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) and [credential storage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store).

Answer (score 0):

#### Auth in browser with Visual Studio Code (With auto renew).

###### Prerequisites

- Install the latest NuGet version.
- Install Azure Artifacts Credential Provider.

https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider

```
wget -qO- https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh | bash
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"
```

###### Inside Visual Studio Code

- open terminal (inside visual studio code)
- run `dotnet restore --interactive`
- Read carefully the prompt `[CredentialProvider]ATTENTION: User interaction required.`
- use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code `display inside the prompt` to authenticate.