# Re-enable Visual Studio Code GitHub authentication

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

For absolutely no reason that I may think of, the Visual Studio Code built-in Git [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) stopped working, only returning authentication failed, not only in Visual Studio Code, but also in the terminal.

A weird thing is that last night it was working fine. Just to wonder today it’s not working any more.

- I use [Ubuntu 21.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_21.04_(Hirsute_Hippo)) (Hirsute Hippo), and I have two-factor authentication enabled in GitHub.
- I tried to create a personal access token, but I can’t find anywhere to put it for Git SCM in Visual Studio Code to work correctly across all repositories without exposing it.

By Visual Studio Code Git SCM stopped working I mean:

- Can't pull/push to a remote repository using the built-in Git extension in Visual Studio Code
- Can't issue the *clone* command for private repositories

How can I re-enable the extension functionalities, without using email and password or appending access token before the remote URL path [as specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231282/how-to-add-github-personal-access-token-to-visual-studio-code)?

PS: I have the [GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) Git extension enabled and it’s authenticated properly in Git (properly working)

Comment: 1. which "VSCode git-scm" plugin do you mean? (there are like hundreds) 2. git or github ? (need more details)

Comment: @xerx593 1. Please recall that I just pointed it to be "BUILT-IN" in VSCode. 2. giti failed to authenticate to GitHub, or did I miss a thing?

Comment: Re *"returning authentication failed"*: What is the full error message? E.g., does it include *"remote: No anonymous write access."*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69954625/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This is a super [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) (because it affects so many). A candidate for the canonical question is *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).

Answer (score 2):

Check first if your remote URL is an HTTPS one (in command-line: once this is working there, you can switch back to VSCode):

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If HTTPS, check what credential helper is used to cache your credentials. An old password might be cached, which is no longer valid, since now only [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) are allowed (following the [Aug. 2021 policy change](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/)).

The follwoing works, even in a simple Windows CMD shell (no git bash required), as long as you have set the PATH:

```bash
# For Windows only
# Replace C:\Program Files\Git by the folder path where your Git is installed
set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"  
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Then, from any shell you want, since Git PATH is referenced:

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-xxx get
```

(replace xxx by the output of `git config --global credential.helper`)

If this is the wrong "password" (ie., not your current token), erase the old one and store the new one.

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-xxx erase
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=MyGitHubUserAccount\npassword=yyy" | git-credential-xxx store
```

(Again, `printf` works in a Windows CMD as well, if the `%PATH%` is set as mentioned before)

Comment: I don't know what is my `xxx` since `git config --global credential.helper` does not return anything. :(

Comment: @Jaider Then, if you are on Windows, you can set it to manager-core. If not, install GCM (cross-platform): https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/#download-and-install=

Comment: Does a full tutorial for this exist for Windows users? Spent hours monkeying with this crap and still not getting anywhere.

Comment: @MC9000 The very same commands are working in a simple Windows CMD shell. I have edited the answer to explain how.

Comment: Weird I did exactly that, but  my installation was corrupted, so I had to reinstall git. works fine now. Thanks!