# How do I successfully connect VSCode to GitHub?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I try to git push, I get this error;

$ git push -u origin main
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Edna0/alx-pre_course.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21112 ms: Timed out

on my notifications menu, I get;

Sign in failed: FetchError: request to https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=9ce9d6e28b23f1f1d29b&state=b0e77a23-cbb0-40e8-868f-38df4ed7fc54 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN vscode-auth.github.com

And also when I try to sync settings, I get this error;

Sign in failed: FetchError: request to https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=9ce9d6e28b23f1f1d29b&state=b0e77a23-cbb0-40e8-868f-38df4ed7fc54 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN vscode-auth.github.com

How do I successfully connect to github with my personal access token without getting these errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a GitHub personal access token to Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231282/how-to-add-a-github-personal-access-token-to-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Your system is attempting to use DNSSEC (security-checked DNS), for whatever reason (probably a good one), but it's not working for whatever reason (probably not a good one). While it's not great for *security* you could look into turning off DNSSEC on your system. How (and whether) to do that is another question entirely.