# How do I set up my local Git repo to use the new personal access token I just created?

Tags: git, github, token, local

I have an existing GitHub repo checked out locally on my Mac.  Because of Git requiring personal access tokens, I created one using the instructions here -- https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token .  However, when I try and push my local changes, I'm not prompted for a token ...

```
$ git push
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myrepo/maps.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How do I set up my local repo to use the token I just created?

Comment: Hope this helps
[where-to-store-the-personal-access-token-from-github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645843/where-to-store-the-personal-access-token-from-github)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your question, Try this it will work,

`git remote set-url origin https://yourgithubusername:yourpersonalaccesstoken@github.com/yourgithubusername/reponame.git`

Then,

To add all changes `git add .`

To commit `git commit -m "commit message"`

To Push Changes `git push origin main`

Comment: Note that this saves the token as clear text in a file in the local repository.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have generated the token, go to `Keychain Access` app in your mac. Search for `github.com`, double-click, and choose `Show Password`, after that hit your macbook password, and enter. You will be able to see the password now and just paste the token you already generated, and save the changes.

That's it