# Using git credentialmanager with github tokens for gists

Tags: windows, git, github, access-token

I'm trying to push my gist to github and trying to do it the right way by using the credential manager as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/52598)

I assumed following simple workflow would suffice

- clone a gist
- pushing would ask credentials (username/token)

Unfortunately, it's either not that simple or I messed up somewhere else. All I get is a `remote: Repository not found.`

---

**Cloning my gist**

```
C:\Users\lieve\AppData\Local\Temp>git clone https://gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d
Cloning into '4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 9
Receiving objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
```

**Show remotes**

```
C:\Users\lieve\AppData\Local\Temp>cd 4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d
C:\Users\lieve\AppData\Local\Temp\4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d>git remote -v
origin  https://gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d (fetch)
origin  https://gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d (push)
```

**Try to push fails and doesn't ask any credential**

```
C:\Users\lieve\AppData\Local\Temp\4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d>git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d/' not found
```

**Credential manager diagnosis**
C:\Users\lieve\AppData\Local\Temp\4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d>git credential-manager-core diagnose
Running diagnostics...

```
 [ OK ] Environment
 [ OK ] File system
 [ OK ] Networking
 [ OK ] Git
 [ OK ] Credential storage
 [ OK ] Microsoft authentication (AAD/MSA)
 [ OK ] GitHub API

Diagnostic summary: 7 passed, 0 skipped, 0 failed.
```

I can get push to work by changing the remote to `https://<token>@gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d` but that's exactly what the credential manager *should* take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Git Credential Manager (GCM)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (previously GCM-core, recently renamed as GCM) depends on the [Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0).

Open said Windows Credential Manager and check if there is any `github.com` entry, which might include the wrong password (like your actual password instead of a token).

Delete that entry, and the next `git push` would ask for your credentials (do use the token as password then).

---

Note: [GCM 2.4.0](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.4.0), Nov. 2023, adds GitHub Gist remote URLs support: [PR 1402](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/pull/1402).

> Update our OAuth, rest API, and dotcom-detection methods that deal with the remote or target URL to correctly support gists URLs.

Comment: Thank you, removing the existing github credential worked. Pushing asked for credentials *(the options provided in the dialogbox are not at all intuitive to me... got it to work by canceling the dialog box so the cli asked a username/password (token).*

Comment: I now have a user/token in credman *intended for that one gist*. It seems that every other repo I have now uses  that credential when pushing (and failing). That means I was totally wrong in creating a PAT per repo? Can there be only one PAT per user/machine?

Comment: @Lie one PAT, with scope repo, should be enough.