# Using multiple git personal access tokens (PAT) with Credential Manager

Tags: git, github, gist, git-credential-manager

I'm using [GitCredentialManager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645843/where-to-store-my-git-personal-access-token/51505417#51505417) but I can't find a way on how to use multiple Personal Access Tokens (PAT).

I have

1. a `Windows terminal` gist at https://gist.github.com/lkeersmaekers/4884d047b3b90ccd697a4d7ec21be49d
2. a `dotvim` repo at https://github.com/lkeersmaekers/dotvim

I created

1. a PAT for the `Windows terminal` gist <sub>(Create gists scope)</sub>
2. a PAT for the `dotvim` repo <sub>(Access public repositories scope)</sub>

When pushing the `Windows terminal` the gist a first time, git asks for a username/password(=PAT) as expected, the push succeeds and I can see the credential in Windows Credential Manager.

When pushing the `dotvim` repo thereafter however uses that stored credential (PAT) from `Windows terminal` and the `dotvim` push fails.

I'm unsure at what is the best practice here.

- Instead of the two PAT's, I could create *one* PAT with enough access rights but that way, I'll probably end up with one PAT with all checkboxes checked which seems utterly wrong.
- I have no idea how to have two credentials in Windows Credential manager that would allow `git push` somehow to use the correct one.

Comment: I don't see why you would ever have a "PAT with all checkboxes checked".

Comment: @matt -me neither, hence my question on how to use two PAT's  with git's credential manager on one computer.

Comment: Git has no credential manager. You do. Git doesn't do authorization. That's between you and the remote site. You can give Git a reference to your credential manager but it is not a Git feature.

Comment: @matt - noted, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple different approaches you can take here.  One is to create a single token with the `gist` and `repo` scopes and use that generally.  That token does have access to all your repositories, but if you're using a credential helper, then it's stored in an encrypted way and it shouldn't be too risky.

Since you're actually using two different domains here (`github.com` and `gist.github.com`), you can use separate tokens without a problem.  Tokens are stored scoped on the domain, so there's no conflict here.  Just use each credential on its respective domain.

If you want to use different tokens for different repositories, you can do that by setting [`credential.usehttppath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-useHttpPath) to `true`.  That can also be scoped to a particular URL pattern (including wildcards) such that you it only applies to GitHub (e.g., with `git config --global credential.https://github.com/.usehttppath true`).  Each repository will then have its own set of credentials, and you can store as many tokens as you like.  If you have a lot of repositories, this will likely become inconvenient quickly, though.

Finally, if you just want to have different tokens for public and private access, you can do this for GitHub by taking advantage of the fact that GitHub ignores the username when you use a token.  You can therefore clone public repositories by putting a `public@` before the hostname (e.g., `https://public@github.com/git/git.git`) and then using `private@` for private repositories.  Git's credential helpers will store separate credentials for these fake usernames and the respective token will be used.

Comment: pushing to `gist.github.com` also uses the `github.com` credential but I'm going with the one token to rule them all option to not to much complicate things so it will not matter in practice. 
If you are interested, this (relvenant) info was output with tracing on: 
`19:05:45.434878 ...GitCommandBase.cs:48 trace: [ExecuteAsync]  **host=gist.github.com**` and `19:05:45.543991 ...\HostProvider.cs:126 trace: [GetCredentialAsync] Looking for existing credential in store with **service=https://github.com account**=...`

Comment: GCM Core may do that, but the Git credential protocol does not: it considers them separate domains.  I would argue that in this case, that's a bug and you may want to use `wincred` as a helper instead.