# How to connect windows credential manager with ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-push, credential-manager

Actually i need some help to connect ubuntu with windows credential manager. Because when I want to push something on my repository ubuntu always want password (Acces token).

I tried git bash and cmd. They're fine with windows credential manager but ubuntu :(.

I tried git config --global user.name and user.email but they're not working.

I added my git account on windows credential manager. But it still same.

Comment: The `user.name` setting is not a *credential* and therefore never affects any credentials. Windows credentials are for Windows systems; Linux systems are not Windows and do not use Windows credentials, hence do not use Windows Credential Manager. Do not try to use the Windows credential manager here: use a different credential manager, or use ssh.

Comment: Which credential manager to use? yeah i know ssh but I just want to solve that specific problem thank you for your support.

Comment: Use any of the standard or nonstandard Ubuntu ones: search SO with `[git] ubuntu credential manager`, you'll find things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46645843/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

I never knew this existed either, but (assuming you're in WSL here) you can point the credential manager to the windows executable like so:

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe"
```

There are a few other config flags you may need to sed, check out the linked doc.

See:

- https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/wsl.md