# Git ssl error on windows

Tags: git, ssl, msysgit, gitorious

I keep getting the following error when attempting to clone a git repository using ssl on windows:

```
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

The ssl certificate hierarchy is trusted (the issuer certificate is added to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities) and I can browse to the hosting site (a private instance of Gitorious) without ssl errors. I've tried cloning on Windows 7 and on Windows Server 2008 and it's failed both times.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid SSL certificate when pushing to Git server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413537/invalid-ssl-certificate-when-pushing-to-git-server)

Comment: http://www.f15ijp.com/2012/08/git-ssl-certificate-problem-how-to-turn-off-ssl-validation-for-a-repo/  one of the best solution which I found

Answer (score 19):

Git Apparently not take certificates saved in windows, you have to specify what editing the path to the certificate file **.gitconfig**

**gitconfig location:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc
```

Add the line (replace  with the path to file and yourCertificate.ctr with the name to your certificate):

```
.
.
.
[help]
    format = html
[http]
    sslVerify = true
    sslCAinfo = C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
    sslCAinfo = [route]/yourCertificate.crt
[sendemail]
    smtpserver = /bin/msmtp.exe

[diff "astextplain"]
.
.
.
```

and try again..

Comment: I was having the same problem with Stash installed on my server. I had to save the certificate as rfc, only then did it work. So, on the server, where I have my keystore I ran this: `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -export -keystore .keystore -rfc -alias tomcat -file yourCertificate.crt`

Comment: Git on Windows no longer uses a .gitconfig file or a curl-ca-bundle.crt in those locations and I'm having trouble finding the right way of doing this now.

Comment: @Chris C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs?

Answer (score 1):

The location of http.sslcainfo is stored in "C:\ProgramData\Git\config".
It is not altered when uninstalling/reinstalling git.

I recently had to change it from

```
sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

to

```
sslCAInfo = C:/Users/kristof/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Also see issue:
Configure http.sslcainfo in Git for Windows' own system-wide config #531
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/531

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add to your Git global config file:

```
 http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Your msysgit instance needs to know where to look for the CA certificates in order to validate them.

See more settings in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094) or in "[Cannot get Http on git to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073504/cannot-get-http-on-git-to-work/7073618#7073618)".

Comment: If I run git clone from Git Bash it works. Only issue in eclipse.

Comment: @JigarShah that could be a question in its own, describing the problem and adding a lot of specific details (what OS, what version of Java, Eclipse, Egit? what version of git?)

Comment: Sorry comment at wrong place. Win8-64Bit, Eclipse Luna, (No special plugin for git but m2eclipse) JDK8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550742/eclipse-luna-git-checkout-ssl-fails/24550864

Comment: @JigarShah you are using an ssh url: you don't need a proxy for that.

Answer (score -1):

If all else fails, you can set the environment variable `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` to `true`. However, it is hopefully possible to resolve the issue in another way. *WARNING:* This exposes you to *SECURITY RISKS*, as you can no longer trust that you're talking to the server you think you're talking to.

Comment: I did the same. same error. In eclipse > git > Configuration > User settings added sslVerify = false. But it seems its not able to connect on ssl itself.