# TortoiseGit remote operations fail with SSL issue : "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When trying a remote operation in TortoiseGit 2.3.0.0 on windows 10, I get:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/*username*/*repo*.git/': SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

There seems to be no problem doing things from the git command line, so it seems to be a TortoiseGit problem.

I recently upgraded git from an old version (1.5 ish) to 2.10.0. - this may be when the problems started. I notice that [there have been some changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128676/2736162) relating to certificates.

I have tried using http.sslVerify false as a diagnostic tactic, <s>but that doesn't make the problem go away</s> which worked once I put the setting in my local (not global) config, though I got some 'cannot spawn sh' errors.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling TortoiseGit.

Comment: This is strange when it works from CLI as TortoiseGit also does exactly the same (just calling git.exe). You can use the way described http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Is-there-a-debug-mode-for-git-clone-https-traffic-td6375651.html for debugging https traffic. Have you set a custom %HOME% environment variable, so that TGit and vanilla git use the very same %HOME%\.gitconfig?

Comment: @MrTux I do have a HOME env var, but as it happens don't have any config there - not in the systemwide location - so I think it's only my local (repo) config in play.

Comment: @MrTux and to confirm, pasting the git command-line from the TortoiseGit command progress window (e.g. `git.exe push --progress "origin" features/ac-3:features/ac-3`) works fine in git bash or the windows command prompt.

Comment: I suppose it's a git config issue where git cli and TGit use different settings (You can go to TortoiseGit settings, on the General page you can request the environment TGit uses). Have you tried setting `http.sslVerify false` directly in the project?

Comment: @MrTux if you mean in the local config - that seemed to help; not sure if the config location was the issue or if the setting was being cached.