# Android Kotlin Project Not upload on Git

Tags: git, github

I created Android Project when i trying to push the project from CMD prompt it show this message

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<userName>/<project_name>/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

how can i resolve this error and not able to upload project

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No

Comment: @evolutionxbox I remove the origin and again add into then its work fine

Comment: So you’ve resolved your issue? May you post an answer, or delete the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid SSL certificate when pushing to Git server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413537/invalid-ssl-certificate-when-pushing-to-git-server)

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the issue using this Commands in Git:

1) Remove the origin

```
git remote rm origin
```

2) Add again the remote origin

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<userName>/<project_name>.git
```

3) Final push your project using Following Command:-

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then git ask your username and password fill it and your project upload successfully on Github.

Hope its helpful

Comment: Good job for solving the issue yourself!