# Can't customize the configuration in .gitconfig separately for the work and personal environment

Tags: windows, git, windows-10, tortoisegit, git-config

I have the following files:

- `C:\Users\User\.gitconfig`

  ```
  [includeIf "gitdir:C:/Development-Personal/"]
      path = development-personal.gitconfig

  [includeIf "gitdir:C:/Development-Work/"]
      path = development-work.gitconfig
  ```
- `C:\Users\User\development-personal.gitconfig`

  ```
  [credential]
      helper = manager
  [user]
      name = PersonalNickname
      email = personal@email.com
  ```
- `C:\Users\User\development-work.gitconfig`

  ```
  [user]
      name = WorkNickname
      email = work@email.com
  [http]
      sslVerify = false
  ```

Then I enter the folder `C:\Development-Work\projects-git`, right-click to a project folder `Project` and select the TortoiseGit client's ex. `commit` command and the pop-up window appears that I have to set the user's name and email before commit.

What do I miss in my configuration? Thank you for the help.

---

- The version of my Git:

  ```
  C:\>git --version
  git version 2.18.0.windows.1
  ```
- The version of my TortoiseGit

  ```
  TortoiseGit 2.6.0.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)
  git version 2.18.0.windows.1 (C:\Program Files\Git\bin; C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\; 
  C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig; C:\ProgramData\Git\config)
  ```

Comment: The above looks correct. Be sure your Git is sufficiently recent (2.13 or later) to support `includeIf`. I don't use Windows, but it might also be reasonable to use `gitdir/i:` to make the path matching case-insensitive.

Comment: PS: sslVerify = false might be dangerous, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128676/3906760

Comment: MrTux: I am aware of this. Thanks. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have a recent enough version of Git (for Windows) installed (IIRC 2.13 or later, best sue the latest version).

`Includeif` does not work correctly until TortoiseGit 2.6.1 (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3184).

Comment: My version of TortoiseGit is 2.6.0.0 (I've edited my question). Checking for updates displayed that I have installed the latest version already.

Comment: You need the latest preview release, http://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/

Comment: I see this version is not officially considered as stable. I'll give it a try, thanks +1.