# Eclipse Luna git checkout ssl fails

Tags: eclipse, git, m2eclipse, jgit

when I try to checkout from git in eclipse Luna it says

```
git@-myrepo:myproj-.git: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )
git@-myrepo:myproj-.git: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )
```

- I am on proxy. its port is 8080 for all http/https.
- I am on Java8
- also configured `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

From command line everything works fine.
By default eclipse reads IE/System proxy settings. I have kept them same.

UPDATE : Issue resolved. Bypassing proxy for our git repo did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, Eclipse connects to the proxy on the wrong port. It would be nice of the software to tell you which port that is but try to set the HTTPS proxy settings in Eclipse's preferences to 443 (as mentioned in the error message).

Or contact your system admins to ask how to configure the proxy settings for HTTPS.

Comment: proxy https via 8080 only works (I can see pages from IE/FF). I also configured -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<HOST>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080     Why its going to 443 ? Also tried 443 but it fails. Connection timeout
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<HOST>

Comment: Eclipse uses 8080 (probably). But your proxy refuses the connection saying "You have to use port 443."

Comment: Issue resolved. It seems better to by pass proxy for git. As that seems to be issue.

Comment: @JigarShah: I see. Please answer your own question with the correct answer for other people who have the same problem.