# How to set up Git to get through a proxy

Tags: git, proxy, github, cygwin

I want to connect to GitHub at work and need to get through the http proxy. I am able to get out for FTP using cURL using the command

> `curl -v -g --ftp-pasv --upload-file MYFILE --proxy PROXYADDRESS:PROXYPORT --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user WINDOWSDOMAIN\WINDOWSUSER:WINDOWSPASSWORD ftp://FTPUSER:FTPPASS@FTPURL/`

I've so far not been able to provide equivalent settings for Git.

I tried following instructions on [Using Github Through Draconian Proxies](http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html) under cygwin.

I've got corkscrew installed and tried to SSH to GitHub

```
ssh github.com
```

or

```
ssh ssh.github.com
```

I get back

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.github.com: hostname nor servname provided, or not known.

I've tried setting the http and https proxy.

Here is the output from git --config -l

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
user.name=Peter Wilkinson
user.email=someemail@gmail.com
github.user=ProggerPete
github.token=shouldprobablykeepthissecret
http.proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
https.proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
```

I've also run

```
export https_proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
export http_proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
set https_proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
set http_proxy=http://somedomain\someuser:somepass@10.167.116.142:80
```

I then try and clone and get.

```
$ git clone https://ProggerPete@github.com/project/JavaScript-Maven-Plugin.git
Cloning into JavaScript-Maven-Plugin...
Password:
error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://ProggerPet
@github.com/project/JavaScript-Maven-Plugin.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

This looks to me like I'm failing authentication with the proxy. However I'm using the same login and pass that works for FTP via cURL.

How can I get connected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After much head bashing I finally stumbled across http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/. It's a proxy proxy that understands ntlm authentication.

I installed it and told it about the http proxy. Then pointed git at CNTLM and it all started working.

I found getting this going very frustrating so hopefully this will help someone else in the same situation.

Comment: That is good to know about. Proxies that only do NTLM authentication are known to be a problem and this looks like a useful work-around. The version of curl provided with msysGit can do NTLM but I seem to remember that git doesn't pass authentication parameters to it.

Comment: Yeah, I could get the curl in msysgit to talk to the proxy from command line, but there seemed no way to pass the the --proxy-ntlm flag when git was using it.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, I cannot use git or ssh into my boxes at work. Does this solution work on ubuntu too? And could you please elaborate on `pointed git at CNTLM`. I am still in the head bashing phase.

Comment: @ali Do you have NTLM to deal with?  I don't seem to need it, though I am running Ubuntu server on an AD/Windows network.  I don't know what kind of proxy server is in my way, though.

Comment: The newest 1.8 msysGit can now speak NTLM, including GSSPI for smartcards (Thanks CURL!)

Comment: ntlmaps if very good also, and it doesn't require admin rights

Comment: @PeterWilkinson Whould you like to introduce step by step to How to pass git through proxy? :/

Answer (score 12):

I usually only need to set:

```
set http_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
set https_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

(note the `https_proxy` refers to the same *http*, not https, proxy address)

See also "[Cannot get Http on git to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073504/cannot-get-http-on-git-to-work/7073618#7073618)".

Comment: Gave it a go, looks like I'm still failing proxy authentication.

Answer (score 6):

You can put proxy information in your ~/.curlrc:

> /home/usr/.curlrc
>
> > proxy = proxy.proxyhost.com:8443
> >     proxy-user = user:pass
> >     proxy-ntlm = true
> >     noproxy = localhost,127.0.0.1,intraweb.company.com

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to be able to get ssh to github tunnelled through your proxy. However as github provides https urls for all their repositories and you can push to that you don't need ssh. If you already have a repository checked out, you can change the url used with

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/project/repo.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://YOURNAME@github.com/project/repo.git
```

(skip the second line if you do not need push access).
This, along with setting the environment variables (https_proxy) as mentioned by VonC will enable access via your proxy.

Comment: I don't have a repo checked out. I'm trying to check one out using git clone https://ProggerPete@github.com/project/JavaScript-Maven-Plugin.git