# Git unable to push to git repository

Tags: git, github

When i try to push to the git repository i get the following error. Please help to solve this problem

```
Test@DT0610QV14001 ~/hello (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/babupca/hello.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

Comment: Always? Or sometimes? Is there a proxy server in your network?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to push via SSH.

Comment: always I get this error

Comment: How to push using SSH, can you guide me

Answer (score 0):

Usually when push via HTTPS fails, it worth trying to switch to SSH:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:babupca/hello.git
```

Of course, you have Github SSH keys to be [set up](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

**Upd:** if SSH way gives you similar error, check [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number).

**Upd:** if you know you are behind proxy, check [another related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734518/how-to-set-up-git-to-get-through-a-proxy).

Comment: I had setup the ssh for github, but i still get the same error. May it is blocked

Comment: Is there any way to push my changes

Comment: $ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.252.129 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number) might help you.

Comment: If neither HTTPS nor SSH works for you, possibly you are behind proxy. See thread about [getting trough it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734518/how-to-set-up-git-to-get-through-a-proxy).

Comment: Thanks for the information zag, i tried most of the options. Still now it is not connecting