# 502 proxy error while pulling the code from git repo

Tags: php, git, github, proxy, bitbucket

I am writing a php script where it clones first and then pulls from a bitbucket git repo.

It works well on my local machine, but on dev server there is proxy configured, so whenever i tried to run the script on server it gives **"502 proxy error"**

when i directly try to clone from command line on dev server it works.
some google links suggested to configure global proxy like

```
git config --global http.proxy proxyserver:port
```

I tried this as well, but not working through script.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up Git to get through a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734518/how-to-set-up-git-to-get-through-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following command before pulling repo in script.

```
git --config http.proxy=http://proxy_host:proxy_port
```