# How to set git http proxy successfully?

Tags: git, proxy

I use the below way to set the proxy in my linux machine.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.xxxxxx.com
git config --global http.proxy $HTTP_PROXY
```

But the below error still happened.

```
[root@xxxxxxx cnpm]#  git clone git://github.com/cnpm/cnpmjs.org ./cnpmjs.org
Cloning into './cnpmjs.org'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
```

ps: In our company, IE proxy is set using http://proxy.xxxxxx.com, and I can download the git project in IE manually.

Comment: try using http/https instead of git://, it's possible the git protocol is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

http_proxy is only valid for http url, not git url.

The [git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol) is a special daemon that comes packaged with Git; it listens on a dedicated port (9418) that provides a service similar to the SSH protocol, but with absolutely no authentication

It is not concerned with http_proxy environment variable.

For GitHub http url environment settings, see:

- "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309)", or
- "[Cannot get Http on git to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073618/6309)"

Comment: thanks. But I really use the git config --global http.proxy $HTTP_PROXY except for the http_proxy

Comment: @liamxu the git config does not matter here as long as you are using a git url. The http setting will be ignored.