# How to connect with the server to git?

Tags: git

I need connect to server git.

http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/
I do everything to the point, 4 point, I add ssh key to the server interface. but what about a 5 point?

I have available repositories nick@source.server.com:title.git

but if I enter the link I get an error

```
ssh: source.server.com:title.git: no address associated with name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means ssh doesn't connect to `source.server.com` (the name doesn't resolve into an ip address), so ssh is looking for a `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file in which it would see what actual hostname it should use when seeing `source.server.com`.
See an example of [config file here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094).

(Note: `HOME` isn't defined by default on Windows, so don't forget to define it)

Point 5 on GitHub help page was about testing the ssh connection to GitHub, not to your server.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: I realized that I needed to do

Comment: "See an example of config file here." - WHAT DO I do with it?

Comment: @denden: actually you shouldn't need one, since `source.server.com` should be resolved by your DNS. Can you `ping source.server.com`? The config file is about defining a shortcut for your ssh url.