# git push origin master> fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: git-push

When I do Git push, I get the following error message -

```
  Username: 
  Password: 
  error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/Selvam-T/hw4_rottenpotatoes.git/info/refs
```

My Git clone read-only address is https://github.com/Selvam-T/hw4_rottenpotatoes.git

I followed the suggestion and changed the repo config to ssh way like this -

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/Selvam-T/hw4_rottenpotatoes.git
```

Then the error message I got, when I did "git push origin master", is this -

```
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:Selvam-T: Name or service not known
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I fix either one of those communication issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https or ssh address to push.

But for https, you need a `~/.netrc` (or `%HOME%\_netrc` on Windows, which supposes you have defined a HOME environment variable), with your GitHub credentials in it.
See "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)" or "[need github without username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021803/need-github-without-username-and-password/11022181#11022181)" for an example.

And for ssh, you need a private / public keys in `~/.ssh`, with the public key published to your repo and a `~/.ssh/config` file.
See "[Why doesn't my SSH key work for connecting to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960897/why-doesnt-my-ssh-key-work-for-connecting-to-github/9963769#9963769)" for more.