# windows git https clone through proxy server failed to write files

Tags: windows, https, github, clone, proxy-server

In the process of cloning a repo through my company proxy server through sysinternal I can see the it tried to write the git repository but failed. However, the .git directory was created but mostly with empty directories.

I have set up my proxy server configuration with "`git config --globlal http.proxy ...`" and "`git config --global https.proxy ...`".
Since I connected to git (I was prompted to enter my account/password), I know the proxy setup works.

From Sysinternal I can see the errors as

```
Query Open C:\Users\myUser\https:\github.com\myGitAccount\source.git\.git  FAST IO DISALLOWED
CreateFile C:\Users\myUser\https:\github.com\myGitAccount\source.git\.git NAME INVALID Denied Access: Read Attributes. Disposition:
```

Github verified that the repo is fine.

Comment: What is the command you are using for cloning your repo (`git clone what?`)? What is your (msys)Git version? And do yo have, in your DOS session, an environment variable `HOME` defined?

Comment: My Git is 1.8. I used "git clone https://github.com/source.git. And no, I don't have a HOME environment variable.

Comment: you appear to be trying to create a directory named 'https:\...' I don't think the ranger is going to like that, yogi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A git clone for an https accessed GitHub repo should be:

```
git clone https://github.com/aUserName/aRepoName.git
```

And it should takes place in a session where HOME is defined if you want to cache your GitHub credentials, as mentioned in "[Git - How to use `.netrc` file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password/6031266#6031266)".

For the proxy, see also "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)".

Comment: Sorry that I mistyped my command. The one I used was "git clone https://github.com/myLogin/myFork.git". The error I have received are:9:49:08.6776457 PM git.exe 4940 QueryOpen C:\Users\jhuang\https:\github.com\jghuang6038\WebFM.git FAST IO DISALLOWED

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. my loing, jghuang6038, my fork:WebFM.git. I used "git clone https://github.com/jghuang6038/WebFM.git". Errors I received: "git.exe 4940 QueryOpen C:\Users\jhuang\https:\github.com\jghuang6038\WebFM.git\.git FAST IO DISALLOWED" and "git.exe 4940 CreateFile C:\Users\jhuang\https:\github.com\jghuang6038\WebFM.git\.git NAME INVALID Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a". Then same for WebFM.git, WebFM.git.git\.git, WebFM.git.git, WebFM.git.bundle, and then WebFM.git.

Comment: @Jules So I suppose that `echo %HOME%` returns C:\Users\jhuang` then? Note: the official clone command is: `git clone https:\github.com\jghuang6038\WebFM` (executed in the parent directory of where you want the directory `WebFM` to be created and its content checked out).

Comment: yes echo %HOME% returns C:\Users\jhuang. From what I have learned it's likely blocked by my company's aniti-virus software. I will need to do more research on that before I waste more of your time. Thanks.