# How to read git push arguments in hook?

Tags: git, bash, shell, hook

I have a Git repository with multiple users. When they push, is it possible for me to read arguments from the client command line? For example, username and password?

I tried `read` in my bash script, but it does not work. I cannot access `STDIN`.

How can I read something from the client command line in a Git hook (update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Git doesn't do any authentication. (See "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309)")

You can get the user id from the https session or the ssh one (if the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file contains that information): that is what [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) does: see "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work)".

You won't certainly get the password. Ever. (And that has nothing to do with git or gitolite).

And gitolite will in turn call git itself (if it authorizes the clone/push/pull command), but git, again, will be blissfully unaware of the user's id requesting said clone/pull/push: it will simply execute it.

Comment: but how github do this?why github allow user do a pushing with http/https ,what should i do is just input my email and password.

Comment: @王振威 GitHub has an Apache which listen to remote request, and will validate user/passwords against their own internal user database. You can store your login/password locally (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094), but they will be used by their GitHub font-end (like an Apache or ssh), not by git or any hook on github side.