# Commit code from eclipse to GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github

How to commit code into GitHub Server using eclipse ?

when I run this command

```
git push -u origin master
```

It shows the following error

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
>   https://github.com/something/something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not expert but i have done this once

think simple and straight way is

1.Download Git to your system

2.cd to your eclipse prject cd /workspace/sampleproject

3.Commands

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/gitusername/reposname.git
git push -u origin master                   this line may throw an error but no problem
```

4.From eclipse ->Help->eclipse marketplace ->search for 'git' -> install  'Egit-git team provider'

5.Go to eclipse ->Windows ->Open perspective ->Git repository

6.From Git repository view on the left side on 'Add existing local repos' then browse to         '/workspace/sampleproject'

7.Now Right click on this added Repository location and add comments press Commit.

8.Now Right click on this added Repository click Push

```
      By default Configured remote repository should be checked then press Next
      From Source Ref and Destination Ref  Select HEAD    //you may change if u want
      Select next give your github username and password then click on Finish.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the https address, you need to pass your credential (Github login and password).
See "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)" for an example.

With Eclipse and Egit, you can set those credential when defining a remote address for your local repo.
See "[Push upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream)".

[image: upstream credential]

Answer (score 0):

Just Open the project perspective and click on Git, you will see the working copies of your project --> right-click on the project and choose the option commit. That's it

or

Right-click on your project and select team you can see various options related to git commands choose commit.

Comment: "commit" doesn't work at all. It looks like it's doing something, but nothing goes into the github repository.