# Git proxy failure need asistance

Tags: git, proxy, connection

I have this error I cannot connect to the proxy I spend 4-5 hours fiddling with the web looking for clues but I cannot resolve this issue..

I am using windows azure and I am having only proxy problem.

My commands are as follows:

1.Connecting with proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<password>@mapevent.azurewebsites.net:443
```

2.Clone Error

```
git clone https://<username>@mapevent.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mapevent.git

Cloning into 'mapevent' ...

fatal: unable to access 'https://<username>@mapevent.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mapevent.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

---

I have also tried with port 8080 but says "cannot resolve" and use push but all seem to fail.

I am new to Git and I am not progressing  :(

Please help me, I have a project to complete in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that http://mapevent.azurewebsites.net/ doesn't need a proxy. It is part of the remote origin url which you want to clone, but the page "[How to Deploy an Azure Web Site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/)" doesn't mention "proxy" at all. Not does the [page using Git](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/).

So make sure to remove the proxy, and try to clone:

```
git config --global --unset-all http.proxy
```

If you were to need a proxy to access to internet, you should already have `HTTP_PROXY` (and `HTTPS_PROXY`) environment variables in place (as I mention in "[could not resolve host `github.com` error while cloning remote repository in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371843/6309)").

But that proxy url (should you actually use one) would certainly *not* be '`<username>:<password>@mapevent.azurewebsites.net:443`': that is part of the url you want to clone.

Comment: Thank you so much! i had no idea.