# Could Not Resolve Host github.com

Tags: javascript, git, ubuntu, browser, github

Though I have the same problem that is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git), But I am facing another problem i.e, even https://github.com/ is not running in the browser and showing that this webpage is not available and this happens after I installed Heroku.

Cannot access github from terminal and not even from browser.

After diagnosis I get to know that this problem is related to my WiFi because when I try to open https://github.com/ in mobile using mobile data, It is opening but when I connect my mobile to WiFi then same problem i.e, this webpage is not available and when I use mobile data internet in my laptop I am able to access the site but when using WiFi this webpage is not available.

I am running Ubuntu(Linux), dual boot with Windows-7

**Diagnosis Results:**

@Aroll605

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=71.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=192 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=137 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=58.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=83.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=104 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=128 ms
```

@epascarello

```
unknown host 192.30.252.131
```

Comment: Please stop inventing your own formatting. `backtickets` are for inline code, not for highlighting URLs, and you don't need to **bold** your URLs.

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming, You need to figure out why a website is blocked on your machine.

Comment: ok @meagar I will remember this.

Comment: Run a basic diagnostic test on your WiFi. 'ping 8.8.8.8' -- if it works, you got a DNS problem. If not, you are not connected to the internet at all. Ping your router, and if there is no response, there is your problem.

Comment: @epascarello Yes on my machine with particular connection(WiFi), but have no idea how to figure out.

Comment: @Aroll605 I have also checked my /etc/hosts file but there is no such entry.

Comment: Run 'ping 8.8.8.8' in Terminal and post the output.

Comment: Can you hit the ip `tracert 192.30.252.131`

Comment: @Aroll605 I will run this but currently I am not carrying machine with me. I will run this as soon as I will reach home. Many Thanks. Will post the output.

Comment: @epascarello I will hit the IP but currently I am not carrying machine with me. I will run this as soon as I will reach home. Many Thanks.

Comment: @epascarello but who's IP(192.30.252.131) is this that you have given ??

Comment: @Aroll605 I have paste the output in the question

Comment: @epascarello I have paste the output in the question.

Comment: This definately looks like a DNS issue, you can access sites via IP but not through the URL. Not programming related like someone else has already said. But It looks like you need to get into your router and setup your DNS servers IP, I would recommend setting to Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Great, Glad to of helped. I'll add an answer below so that you can mark this question answered.

Comment: @Scriptable Now I am using google DNS server address , but previously it was automatically detected, will it affect anything.

Comment: no, it should not cause you any issues, I generally use Google's and find it to be much faster than my ISP's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67980/discussion-between-veer-and-scriptable).

Comment: [Indian Government Orders 32 Web Sites Blocked, Including GitHub, Archive.Org, Pastebin, DailyMotion And Vimeo](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20141231/02075529554/indian-government-orders-32-web-sites-blocked-including-github-archiveorg-pastebin-dailymotion-vimeo.shtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This definately looks like a DNS issue, you can access sites via IP but not through the URL.

You need to configure your routers DNS settings, personally I would set them to Google's DNS servers

```
8.8.8.8 (primary)
8.8.4.4 (secondary)
```