# Github webpage is not available. Can anyone help me?

Tags: github, dns, html, router

I cannot open the github webpage using my home Comcast network.
The problem I have might be the same as 
[Could Not Resolve Host github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717443/could-not-resolve-host-github-com).

But since the DNS of my router Comcast providers is static, I cannot change it. So does anyone know how I can fix it? It works if I change my router into bridge mode but the wifi is disabled due to that.
My router is Arris tg862.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed Comcast router into to bridge mode and connected with my own WIFI router.
But still I don't know the reason behind it. It seems the Comcast router has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your connectivity issue isn't a side-effect of the current [**Large Scale DDoS Attack on github.com**](https://github.com/blog/1981-large-scale-ddos-attack-on-github-com).

It has been going on for two days now (since March 26th, 2015), and has very wide repercussion for all GitHub clients.

Comment: I don't know. Even I cannot open the link you given. If it is the case, what can I do?

Comment: @Elizabeth then it means the issue is not with GitHub, but on your side or somewhere in the middle. You can start with simple checks as in http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-if-You-Can%27t-Access-a-Particular-Website. Also check nslookup (as in http://serverfault.com/q/546200/783)

Comment: But I can open github after switch my comcast router to Bridge Mode. Do you know what this mean?

Comment: @Elizabeth that means using it as plain modem: see http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Home-Networking-Router-WiFi/Gateways-and-Bridge-Mode/td-p/2419143

Comment: @ VonC Thanks. But I mean so if the DDOS is the case, how could bridge mode help?

Comment: @Elizabeth no, in this case the DDoS should not be a factor: only your setup in your modem/router.

Comment: @ VonC right. So back to the question, what is wrong?

Comment: @Elizabeth that would depend on your material, the goal being to see if a wireless bridge works (as in this example: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4194)

Comment: @ VonC sorry. Still have no clue.