# git push -u origin main fatal: unable to access

Tags: git, github

I have installed git-bash on my laptop and trying to push my project on my GitHub account, but it shows this:

```
$ git push -u origin main fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git/': 
Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I have tried the command several times and checks other things. Sometimes I found, this command made the bash screen stuck, doing nothing. -_-

I have tried this command to ensure that the remote is correct:

```
$ git remote -v
```

and get this:

```
origin  https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git (push)
```

I checked my username and email in git config using:

```
$ git config user.email
$ git config --global user.password
```

Found all this stuff ok what I have tried.

Comment: Your PC does not resolve the host `github.com`.

Comment: This appears to be a network issue

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variables, if you are behind a proxy, as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371843/6309).
Or the opposite: you have the wrong proxy specified in Git:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Or, depending on your situation:

- you might need to use your corporate VPN to access internet.
- you might [double-check your git bash `/etc/resolv.conf` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663576/6309).
- you need to check [your DNS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721185/6309)