# Fatal Error : Can't resolve host github.com

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to push files to my remote repository from my local repository and I see this

> fatal error : fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vinivasundharan/abcd.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'github.com'

My computer is not using any Proxy because I have seen methods to resolve the issue when Proxy is being used.

I have tried the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git). But both doesn't seem to help. My system has an active internet connection using Windows 7.

UPDATE

`git config -l` returns the following. I had to post it because I do not what exaclty this means

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/vav9sw/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=xyz
user.email=xyz@gmail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/vinivasundharan/abcd.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
```

EDIT

Just to make sure that i have followed the steps to Upload the file to GitHub check the attached image to see the steps i have followed.

[image: steps]

Comment: so you can visit github via your browser?

Comment: yes. I can visit the website. i cant see any files in the folder though

Comment: Have you configured/changed your SSL settings?

Comment: Does `git config -l` returns lines with 'proxy' in them?

Comment: i haven't changed any SSL settings

Comment: @VonC: check the updated question. I have added what it returned when i executed the `git config-l`

Comment: It seems more like a DNS issue.  Does `ping github.com` work from the command prompt?  If not, the problem is with your network/network settings.

Comment: @jszakmeister :  You are right. ping doesnt work. But it doesnt work for google.com either. It keeps on showing `Request timed out` What change could be made to get it working. If there is a dns issue will i be able to access websites from my system?

Comment: Hard to say--and StackOverflow isn't really the place for the answer.  I don't run Windows these days (I'm a Linux/OS X guy--I abandoned Windows at home some time in 2001).  The things I would check are that you are getting a valid ip address and that a valid DNS server is being assigned (you should be able to ping whatever address is being provided).  I can't tell you how to fix any of it--many problems are very specific to an environment.  And no, if `ping github.com` and `ping google.com` are failing to resolve the ip address, you will not likely be able to access other websites.

Comment: Do you think i should migrate the question to another SE site? But i am able to access all websites. But the ping doesnt work. :(

Comment: can you clone again that repo? (and try and push from the new clone?).
Also, what does a `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1; git push` returns?

Comment: @VonC : it returns the usual warning that i get when tryin to use `git push` instead of `git push origin master`

Comment: @ViniVasundharan Were you able to clone that repo? (in a new local folder)

Comment: @VonC: When I try using `git clone https://github.com/vinivasundharan/testnew1.git` it shows couldnt resolve host. I can`t clone from the remote repository to the desktop as well. It fails as well.

Comment: OK. `export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`: after that a `git clone` is supposed to show a bit more. But if it shows only `Couldn't resolve host 'github.com'`, then try the same from a CMD (not a bash session)

Comment: Ok i get the fatal error again. I really do not know how i could do the same in a cmd. I tried executing the commands from the folder where the local git repository is saved. But it doesn't identify any of the git commands.

Answer (score 15):

This solved my problem:

```
http version:

git config --global --unset http.proxy

https version:

git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: Me neither, by the way I'm using Mac

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, if you've any third party firewall (or internet activity monitor) installed, then configure them to allow your client to access outside connection.

If there aren't any 3rd part firewallls, then go to control panel, search for firewall. Inside the firewall panel, select **Add a new exception** (or similar option). Allow the git client both inbound and outbound access.

Comment: I do not have access tot he firewall settings in my system . :( Maybe it is possible that that is the issue. So it ends up in such a way that I will not be able to use github.

Comment: I am sorry I cant accept this as the answer as I could never check if this solution would achieve what I am looking for..

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to switch to ssh.

You can get github ssh link from same place where https one. Then you just have to generate/add your ssh key to github profile. And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the GitHub client on Windows 10. Running as administrator seemed to fix it.