# git commands(push, pull, clone) not working on android studio - google cloud repository

Tags: git, android-studio, repository, google-cloud-platform

I have an android studio project that is shared through a google cloud repository. I have been using the cloud repository with the inbuilt git commands in android studio for a while now. After the 2.3.2 android studio update, I am unable to push my code into the repository, pull the code from the repository or clone the repository.

When I select upload project on android studio, the event log shows:

```
Fetch failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/mycloudname-1218/': Couldn't resolve host 'source.developers.google.com'

Update canceled
```

Anyone know what the issue is? I tried to import my current project into another cloud (which would solve my issue if it worked fine after) but it keeps giving me the error "Project is already on google cloud platform" (which it is)

Anybody who can help?

Comment: I am not sure about your actual configuration but in most cases I found the issue was http proxy e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667782/fatal-error-cant-resolve-host-github-com). Did you try `git config --global --unset https.proxy` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with VPN. Was fixed after updating the proxy settings.