# Unable to do git cloning repositary

Tags: git

I am trying to run this command (git clone https://ci.open-paas.org/stash/scm/meet/meetings.git) in command line on ubuntu, but it shows error

Cloning into 'meetings'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://ci.open­pass.org/stash/scm/meet/meetings.git/': Could not resolve

host: ci.open­pass.org

what should i do?

Comment: works perfectly fine for me. do you have a VPN running ? were you able to clone other repos in the past ? (trying to understand if this is a repo specific issue / you machine's config issue)

Comment: see if any of these solutions work for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git

Comment: is it necessary to create account to github for cloning repositary, this command was running properly on ofiice's system, os is ubuntu 14.04 and here in my laptop , i am using 16.04 ubuntu , but here this command shows error..

Comment: no. a account is not mandatory. did any of the solutions in that link help ? setting proxy ? unsetting proxy ? reconnecting to wifi ? "netsh int ip reset
" ? try using http:// instead of https://, maybe ?

Comment: I notice that in the error message, you're missing a hyphen between open and pass. Might want to double check that you ran the clone on the right url :) If so, could you run `dig ci.open-pass.org` in a terminal and let us know what it outputs?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found this helpful , so other can refer it.:)

Answer (score 1):

It's 'paas' not 'pass' - you got a typo

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, there is a typo. 
Try as following

```
git clone https://ci.open-pass.org/stash/scm/meet/meetings.git
```

For proxy setting you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git?lq=1)

Hope it helps!