# git cannot push to repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push into a repository, and it does exist and the link is correct. I am trying to force for it to ask me for username and password because I think something is wrong with that. This is the error:

```
λ git push origin master --force -v
Pushing to https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git/' not found
```

Comment: Public or Private?

Comment: it is private but even when i make it public it doesn't work

Comment: what error do you get when you make it public? Do you still get the not found error, or do you get a username / password error?

Comment: still not found

Comment: so not found error tells me its not to do with your credentials, im betting you have a typo or syntax error in your git url

Comment: try `git remote rm origin` and then `git remote add origin https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git/`

Comment: try just cloning the repo:

git clone https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git

Comment: well if I have copied the url there is no way it's a typo. it probobly is with credentials that's why I try to do -v to get it to force it

Comment: λ git clone https://www.github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git
Cloning into 'liveandnow'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git/' not found

Comment: Normally GitHub gives a 403 for bad auth, so I suspect network more than credentials.  However, pursuing the credentials route, run `git config --list` and post back any `credential` entries (ex `credential.helper`), and check for [_~/.git-credentials _ or _$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/credentials_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#FILES)

Comment: user.name=u1358595 so it is wrong how can that be changed? // it does give me error 403 now

Comment: An update to your question with the current output might help in getting an answer.  `user.name` is not used for authentication.  If you are not being prompted for credentials see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/1072626.

Comment: Double check the credentials being used. It is possible that you're not specifying credentials, and the stale ones are being picked from the git-credential. Git(Hub?) will tell you that the repository does not exist even we don't have permissions to access it, which is a sane thing to do, to prevent probing attacks.

Comment: this is misleading tip, the reason of failure is your current account has no privilege to push, grant push privilege or try `git remote add origin`  with correct account in url

Answer (score 3):

The trailing slash error (afaik) can't be removed just by entering the same origin again. In my case, unsuccessfully, I removed my remote, then added it again:

```
git remote remove origin  
git remote add origin https://github.com/andybywire/jekyll-foundation.git
```

But when I tried to push my changes, I still got the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github/andybywire/jekyll-foundation.git/': Could not resolve host: github
```

... trailing slash intact. After some further investigation I noticed that some of my other repos leave the `.git` off altogether:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/andybywire/content-first-prototyping (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/andybywire/content-first-prototyping (push)
```

When I removed the `.git` from the first repo, the error went away entirely:

```
git remote remove origin  
git remote add origin https://github.com/andybywire/jekyll-foundation
```

This repo now allows me to do everything I would expect.

I don't know why, but I also went round and round with this (restarts, [proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git), toggling wi-fi); this is what worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the trailing slash on your URI.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/wojlive/liveandnow.git
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Strange, can you make the repo public so I may try? It seems to currently be private and I can not see it in your account when I visit `https://github.com/wojlive/`. I have just created my own test repo, and this should work as expected. Which version of git are you running?

Comment: latest version i will make it public now

Comment: how do you remove local credentials?

Comment: You can try reading the file at `.git/config` - this may have something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This also works. Avoids the slash altogether.

`git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/NEW_REPO.git`

The result of this command can be seen in `git config -l`:

```sh
...
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/NEW_REPO.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

(If needed), create a new repo first: [Is it possible to create a remote repo on GitHub from the CLI without opening browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423777/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-repo-on-github-from-the-cli-without-opening-br)