# publishing angular 6 application in github pages

Tags: node.js, angular, git, angular-cli-ghpages

I have been battling with getting my application up and running in github pages.

i have a hosted repo which i used for testing purpose and i have follow all the steps needed to get the application up and running but all effort avail abortive

- git init
- git add READMe.md
- git commit -m "first commit"
- git remote add origin repo url
- git push origin master
- npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages
- ng build --prod --base-href https://username.github.io/repo/
- ngh

**after this point i am getting the below errors**

---

An error occurred!
 Error: Unspecified error (run without silent option for detail)
    at C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\index.js:232:19
    at _rejected (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
    at C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)
    at C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)

i have also tried all possible suggestions online but none worked for me... pls i need help in what i am doing wrong.

update as requested

---

C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Angular\application>ngh --no-silent
Cloning https://github.com/Nazehs/application.git into ......\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages.cache

An error occurred!
 { ProcessError: Cloning into '......\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages.cache'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Nazehs/application.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'github.com'

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:47:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
```

code: 128,
  message: 'Cloning into \'..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\'...\nfatal: unable to access \'https://github.com/Nazehs/application.git/\': Couldn\'t resolve host \'github.com\'\n',
  name: 'ProcessError' }

new output of the result

---

Cleaning

Fetching origin

Checking out origin/gh-pages

Removing files

Copying files

Adding all

An error occurred!
 { ProcessError: warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in 3rdpartylicenses.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
error: open("karma.conf.js"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file karma.conf.js
fatal: adding files failed

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:47:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
```

code: 128,
  message: 'warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in 3rdpartylicenses.txt.\nThe file will have its original line endings in your working directory.\nerror: open("karma.conf.js"): Permission denied\nerror: unable to index file karma.conf.js\nfatal: adding files failed\n',
  name: 'ProcessError' }

new error

---

Pushing

An error occurred!
 { ProcessError: fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nazehab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli-ghpages\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:47:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
```

code: 128,
  message:
   'fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.\n   An error occurred while sending the request.\r\nbash: /dev/tty: No such device or address\nerror: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)\nfatal: could not read Username for \'https://github.com\': No error\n',
  name: 'ProcessError' }

Comment: Can you use `ngh --no-silent` and post the result?

Comment: find the result i got from the command

Comment: cool .. 'verbose is love, verbose is life' :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of incorrect proxy settings. 
So, if you have proxy you have to add it to the git config or environment variables.

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login>:<password>@proxy:port
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<login>:<password>@proxy:port
set NO_PROXY=localhost,my.company
```

Note the `NO_PROXY`, to allow to access internal site to your company

You also can register that in your git config:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<login>:<password>@proxy:port
```

OR, if you don't have proxy you can try to unset the proxy settings

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

https version:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: i have tried unsetting the proxy but it seems not to be anything better than the previous. i am still getting the same output after unsetting the proxy.

Comment: check this if any of the solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git

Comment: are you behind any proxy?

Comment: it seems not working popping with another error  after trying some of the hacks there... it's reaching the pushing state then the error

Comment: i am not behind any proxy... i have tried in my two different systems and they seems to get stuck at the same point.. i am properly not getting something right