# Could not resolve host: github.com ONLY in windows bash

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed ubuntu 18.04(WSL) in my win 10 64 bit, 1903.

For the command `git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git`,

it works well in `git bash`(git for windows) and `ubuntu 18.04` shell but not in `bash` (C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe), the error message is

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
Cloning into 'fastText'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I have only two `.gitconfig` file in my pc, one for `git bash` and another for `ubuntu 18.04` shell. I think `ubuntu 18.04` shell may equal to `bash` in some degree but the `bash` must have problems.

[image: 1]

Comment: First try to `ping stackoverflow.com`, if not works check if Windows Firewallis blocking connections. Also try to add nameserver with `rm /etc/resolv.conf; echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 > /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 25):

It could be that your `/etc/resolv.conf` file is corrupt - it happened to me!

Symptoms are:

- Inside WSL `/etc/resolv.conf` is not plain text but some binary garbage. It should be plain text.
- You cannot e.g. `ping google.com` or `ping stackoverflow.com` from inside WSL.
- You can ping those domains OK from powershell in the windows host. Windows git also works OK.

Aside: Interestingly `ping github.com` fails for me today on all my machines but that doesn't stop me from visiting github in my browser or using git - strange.

The solution is to `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf` and restart WSL - windows will recreate that file for you and you should be able to ping away and use git once more from within WSL.

To restart WSL - open a Powershell terminal in Administrator mode and run the following commands. (taken from @germa-vinsmoke 's answer)

```
wsl --shutdown
Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service
```

Answer (score 17):

1. Edit your `wsl.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
```

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

2. Save this file and exit. Then edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

3. Add/Edit this line

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

4. Then close your **WSL console**. Open Powershell with admin and shutdown the wsl.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

5. At last, restart the wsl service

```
Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service
```

More info - [WSL2 - No internet connectivity. DNS Issues(Temporary failure in name resolution)](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6404)

Edit 1 [By P.hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7618421/p-hunter):

When your are behind an VPN, you need to set your nameserver to same what the VPN provides.

For that -

1. Go to Network Status (On Windows) and click on change adapter settings.
2. Find the adapter of your VPN, right click on it and open properties.
3. Find IpV4 option from the dropdown, and open it.
4. Find the DNS mentioned and use the same in Step 3.

Answer (score 10):

I did the following step to resolve the issue:

1. Check the connection to the internet.

```
ping stackoverflow.com
```

2. Edit /etc/resolv.conf, in my case the reason is due to the `nameserver 172.22.16.1`

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

add the nameserver to point to google server

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and add a comment to the original nameserver by adding #

3. Repeat step 1 to cross-check the connection again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did the trick for me on Windows 11 using VS Code and Ubuntu through WSL. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem on Windows 10 using Linux through a Virtual Machine.

Comment: wow this solved it for me also. why nameserver is set to 127.x.x.x in WSL to begin with?

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for me. But this [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6404#issuecomment-810538101) from this [Github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6404) did. Reposting for ease:

It seems launching the VSCode daemon messes things up

1. Make this your `/etc/wsl.conf` file

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

2. Shutdown wsl

```
wsl --shutdown
```

3. Start wsl and create the file: `/etc/resolv.conf` containing

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

P.S. if this answer doesn't help, others on the [Github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6404) might!

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you have problems with proxying.

Try it:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Similar problem: [#20370294](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20370294/10406186) and [#5377703](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5377703/10406186)

Comment: I take a try but not work, I don't think it's problem with proxying because that command works well  in `git bash` and `ubuntu 18.04` shell.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this was the thing that keyed me into the real problem (Which I got from the GitHub thread):

> Find out nameserver with windows powershell (during VPN Session and
> without) using nslookup

So I did:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> nslookup
```

That showed me that I had a CISCO VPN running in the background, that I had completely forgotten about. FWIW.

When I shut that down, everything was working (I had tried most things in this thread, so I don't know what actually solved it)

But I did:

EDIT /etc/wsl.conf

```
[network]                                                                        
generateResolvConf = false
```

And Edit /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

And in powershell did:

```
 wsl --shutdown
```

And nothing worked until I shutdown the VPN, and then I was up and running.