# I pasted Github git URL for cloning but get: Could not resolve host: github.com

Tags: github

I  paste the HTTP but it doesn't work.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Msajjad313/coursera-test1.git
Cloning into ‘coursera-testi’...
Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Msajjad313/coursera-test1.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not resolve host github.com error while cloning remote repository in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to access might not be public, so if its accessible from your git account, you will have to log in to your git account though the terminal.

First: `git config --global user.name "your_username"`

Then: `git config --global user.email "your_email_address@example.com"`

You can follow the process and read more about it [HERE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#configure-git)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the repo, I can clone it without problem. No need to set credentials

Answer (score 2):

```
Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Means you have a DNS or Firewall problem.

Try from a command line:

```
ping github.com
```

There is nothing wrong with the repo, I can clone it without problem.

Comment: This answer guided me to `ping github.com` and got this error `ping: github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`. Then, I found the solution at https://www.tecmint.com/resolve-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/ , and the command `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` did the trick. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running  **WSL Ubuntu**
and facing such kind of issues, follow the Steps below:

**Step 1.** Inside WSL2, create or append file: **/etc/wsl.conf**

**Step 2.** Put the following lines in the above **.conf** file in order to ensure the your DNS changes do not get blown away

```
   sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf << EOF
   [network]
   generateResolvConf = false
   EOF
```

**Step 3.** In a `cmd`**window** (!!), run `wsl --shutdown`

**Step 4.** Start WSL2

**Step 5.** Run the following inside WSL2 (line with search is optional)

```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
   sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf << EOF
   search yourbase.domain.local
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 1.1.1.1
   EOF
```

For source of the original answer,
you can proceed to the following link in      askubuntu.com ->

Refer the Answer by @matson kepson

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192347/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-on-wsl/1401317#1401317?newreg=6b8a0ed0492a44de8c8d2982ab4ebcab%60%60%60)

Thank me later.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33009985)

Comment: Thanks @James for enlightening me. I am a newbie here.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow must be written by yourself. You may quote parts of other sources, but you must make clear they are quotes, and clearly attribute your source(s).